# Prove 7 divides $15^n+6$ with mathematical induction

Tags: induction

Prove that for all natural numbers statement n, statement is dividable by 7

$$15^n+6$$

**Base.** We prove the statement for $n = 1$

15 + 6 = 21 it is true

**Inductive step.**

*Induction Hypothesis.* We assume the result holds for $k$. That is, we assume that

$15^k+6$

is divisible by 7

*To prove:* We need to show that the result holds for $k+1$, that is, that

$15^{k+1}+6=15^k\cdot 15+6$

and I don't know what to do

Comment: If you have a problem actually writing down the inductive argument, take a look at Arturo's good general advice in this post and try and apply it to your problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19370/demonstration-by-induction-1an-1an/19377#19377

Comment: @Derek Jennings: Like this?

Comment: @Templar: Let's say it's heading in the right direction but it would not be accepted as a full answer as you have not finished off the inductive step using the induction hypothesis, though no doubt you can do this since you've accepted Apostolos's answer. Remark: induction is overkill for this problem since $15 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ and so $15^n \equiv 1 \pmod{7}.$

Comment: @Derek: I agree that congruence considerations give a shorter and more insightful solution than induction.  Whether induction is overkill depends upon how comfortable the student is with congruence arguments (and, for instance, whether s/he knows the concept of congruence at all).  I recently taught a "transitions" course that covered both of these topics, and a lot of my students were -- surprisingly to me -- more comfortable with the induction argument.

Comment: (The point, I guess, is that congruences are more abstract than induction.  Some people are better at problem solving than thinking abstractly; others the reverse...)

Comment: @Pete: That's an interesting point you make.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Observe that $14$ is divisible by 7. Then let $15^k\cdot 15+6=15^k\cdot 14+ 15^k+6$.

Answer (score 6):

By induction hypothesis, you have $15^k=7t-6$.

Comment: Could you explain more about it?

Comment: @Templar: $15^{k+1}+6=15^k\cdot 15+6 = (7t-6)\cdot 15+6=7\cdot 15t-90+6=7(15t-12)$

Comment: So you just guess that $15^k=7t-6$ and then prove that is true, right?

Comment: @Templar: No, the induction hypothesis says that $15^k+6$ is a multiple of $7$. So $15^k+6=7t$ for some integer $t$.

Comment: Ah, I got it, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Often textbook solutions to induction problems like this are magically "pulled out of a hat" - completely devoid of intuition. Below I explain the intuition behind the induction in this proof. Namely, I show that the proof easily reduces to the completely trivial induction that $\rm\ \color{#c00}{1^n \equiv 1}$.

Since $\rm\ 15^n + 6 = 15^n-1 + 7\:,\: $ it suffices to show that $\rm\ 7\ |\ 15^n - 1\:.\: $ The base case $\rm\ n=1\ $ is clear. The inductive step, slightly abstracted, is simply the following

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \begin{align} &7\ |\ \ \color{#0a0}{c\ -1},\ \ \ \color{#90f}{d\ -\ 1}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ 7\ |\ cd\,-\,1 = (\color{#0a0}{c-1})\ d + \color{#90f}{d-1}\\[.2em]
{\rm thus} \ \ \ \ &7\ |\ 15-1,\ 15^n-1\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ 7\ |\ 15^{n+1}-1\end{align}$

$\rm Said\ \ mod\ 7,\ \ 15\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ 15^n\equiv \color{#c00}{1^n\equiv 1}\ $ by inductively multiplying ("powering") using this:

**Lemma** $\rm\ \ \ \ \ A\equiv a,\ \ B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ AB\equiv ab\ \ (mod\ m)\quad\ $ [**Congruence Product Rule**)

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A-a,\:\:\ B-b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A-a)\ B + a\ (B-b)\ =\ AB - ab $

Notice how this transformation from divisibility form to congruence arithmetic form has served to reduce the induction to the triviality $\rm\, \color{#c00}{1^n \equiv 1}$. Many induction problems can similarly be reduced to trivial inductions by appropriate conceptual preprocessing. Always think before calculating!

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/794719/242) for much further discussion on this topic.