# Show $11$ divides $3^{2n+2}+2^{6n+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I was requested to show $11|3^{2n+2}+2^{6n+1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I tried using induction. Since $n=1$ yields $81+128=209=11\cdot 19$ we can safely assume $3^{2k+2}+2^{6k+1}=11m$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we can consider the case for

$$3^{2(k+1)+2}+2^{6(k+1)+1}=3^{2k+4}+2^{6k+7}$$

Notice that
$$
\begin{align} 
3^{2k+4}+2^{6k+7} &= 3^{2k+2+2}+2^{6k+1+6} \\ &=3^{2k+2}\cdot 3^2+2^{6k+1}\cdot2^6
\end{align}
$$

This seems promising, but I can't find anything to do with it. Yes, we assumed $11|3^{2k+2}+2^{6k+1}$. However, for $11$ to divide a linear combination of the two terms (as the one we find in our inductive step), we should know $11$ divides each term separately, which is *not* something we know.

Another despaired attempt was trying to make use of the fact that $3$, $2$ and $11$ are all primes. I know $m|n$ if and only if, for their prime factorizations $m=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}...p_k^{e_k}, n=p_1^{f_1}p_2^{f_2}...p_k^{f_k}$, we have $e_i \leq f_i$ for all $i$. However, what can we know about the prime factorization of $3^{2k+2}+2^{6k+1}$?

I'm pretty sure using induction is not the simplest way to show this (and I'm totally sure prime properties is completely desperate), and yet I have no other ideas on how to go about the problem. How can this property be demonstrated?

Comment: $2^6\equiv-2(\mod11)$ and $3^2\equiv-2(\mod 11)$

Comment: It's much easier to begin with $n=0$.

Comment: It's $\,11\mid 9(9^n)+2(64^n),\,$ true by $\!\bmod 11\!:\ 9(9^n) \equiv \color{#c00}{-2(64^n)}\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{-2}\equiv 9\equiv \color{#c00}{64}\,$ & the Congruence Product Rule. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/794719/242) in the linked dupe for how to mechanically translate this modular arithmetic proof into an inductive proof, and follow the linked questions in the dupe for many more worked examples.

Comment: You are almost done!

For the possible final step observe that, 

$$\begin{align}3^{2k+4}+2^{6k+7}&=9\left(11m-2^{6k+1}\right)+2^{6k+7}\\
&=99m-9\cdot2^{6k+1}+2^{6k+7}\\
&=99m+2^{6k+1}\left(2^6-9\right)\\
&=11\left(9m+5\cdot 2^{6k+1}\right).\end{align}$$

This completes your proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3^{2n+2}+2^{6n+1}=9^{n+1}+32^n\cdot2^{n+1}=(11-2)^{n+1}+2^{n+1}(33-1)^n$ This implies $$3^{2n+2}+2^{6n+1}\equiv(-2)^{n+1}+2^{n+1}(-1)^n\pmod{11}$$ We can see that for both $n$ odd and even one has $$3^{2n+2}+2^{6n+1}\equiv0\pmod{11}$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: You are a respectable member of MSE and as such I respect you. My English is very poor and without the Google translator I would not be able to give answers to certain problems. In this sense I did not understand at first glance what you wanted to tell me (in particular I do not know what FAQ means). But I'll try to follow your advice after seeing all this clear. Best regards.