# $n$ divides $a_1 - a_2$ as well as $b_1 - b_2$. Show that $n$ divides $a_1b_1 - a_2b_2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I keep arriving at $a_1b_1$ and $a_2b_2$ having the same sign if I multiply the equations $a_1 - a_2 = nk$ and $b_1 - b_2= np$ times each other. They must be opposite signs so that I can say that $n$ divides the difference of the two hence they are equivalent classes under $Z_8$. Any hints please. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is the [Congruence Product Rule](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242) in divisibility form. It is much clearer in congruence form. Follow the link for both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ a_1 b_1 - a_2 b_2 = (a_1-a_2) b_1 + a_2(b_1-b_2). $$
$n$ divides both the brackets, so it also divides the sum.