# Prove by induction that $\forall n\geq 1,\ 7\mid 3^{2n+1} + 2^{n-1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Prove by induction that $$7 \mid 3^{2n+1} + 2^{n-1},\ \forall n\geq 1$$

Base case $n=1$:

$$3^{2 × 1+1} + 2^{1-1} = 28.$$

Induction:

$$P(k): 3^{2k+1} + 2^{k-1},\ P(k+1): 3^{2(k+1)+1} + 2^{(k+1)-1}.$$

$$3^{2k+3} + 2^k = 9 \times 3^{2k+1} + 2^{k-1} \times 2 = 7 \times 3^{2k+1} + 2 \times 3^{2k+1} + 2^{k-1} \times 2.$$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: For $n=1$ the claim is not true. So check that and indicate a more specific issue you are having with this.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't done editing and accidentally clicked enter

Comment: This is much better.

Comment: Sorry guys!!! New to the site, and working my way to getting down proper formatting.

Comment: ok try substituting $b=3^{2k+1}+2^{k-1}$. What do you know about $b$?

Comment: Without induction: $$3^{2n+1}+2^{n-1} = 3 \cdot 9^n + 2^{n-1} \equiv 3 \cdot 2^n + 2^{n-1} = 6 \cdot 2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}= 7 \cdot 2^{n-1}  \equiv 0 \bmod 7.$$

Comment: Not by induction but using 9 == 2 mod 7: 3^(2n-1)+2^(n-1) = 3.9^n + 2^(n-1) == 3.2^n + 2^(n-1) (mod 7) = 3.2.2^(n-1) + 2^(n-1) = 2^(n-1)(3.2 + 1) = 7.2^(n-1) which is a multiple of 7.qed. Oh, HeinrichD beat me by 1 minute.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze That does use induction, but it the induction is  hidden in the proof of the Congruence Product or Power Rule - see my answer and its links for more on such.

Comment: @HeinrichD See above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that from your assumption you have:

$3^{2k+1} +2^{k-1} = 7p,\quad p\in\mathbb{Z}$

Then you can change the following line you have:

$9 \cdot3^{2k+1} + 2^{k-1} \cdot 2$

into:

$2(3^{2k+1}+2^{k-1})+7\cdot3^{2k+1} = 2\cdot 7p+7\cdot3^{2k+1}=7(2p+3^{2k+1})$

which is divisible by $7$ as required.

Comment: Was going to explain why this works but you beat me to the punch.

Comment: I get it now, I was struggling with coming up with $2(3^{2k+1}+2^{k-1})$. I'm fairly certain I understand $\quad p\in\mathbb{Z}$, but can you clairify that for me?

Comment: @user6391985 It comes straight from the definition of "divides". That is to say $7|3^{2k+1}+2^{k-1} \iff 3^{2k+1}+2^{k-1}=7p$ for some $p\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Oh ok I get it, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @calculator2compiler This proof can be viewed more intuitively as a special case of (the proof of) the Congruence Product Rule - see my answer and its links.

Answer (score 3):

*Intuitively*  the induction step can be viewed as an application of the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), i.e. applying the rule to multiply the first two congruences yields the third congruence - as sought.

$$ \begin{align}{\rm mod}\,\ 7\!:\qquad\quad {9^{\color{#c00}{\large 1}}}  \equiv&\ \  {2}^{\color{#c00}{ \large 1}}\\[2pt] 
-3\cdot 9^{\large \color{#0a0}n}\equiv&\ \ 2^{\large \color{#0a0}n-1}\qquad\!  {\rm i.e.}\ \  P(\color{#0a0}n)\\[-4pt]
\overset{\rm multiply}\Longrightarrow\,\   {-}3\cdot 9^{\large  \color{#0a0}{\color{#c00}1+n}}\equiv&\ \  2^{\large \color{#c00}1+\color{#0a0}n-1}\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ P(\color{#0a0}{{\color{#c00}1}\!+\!n})\end{align}\ \qquad $$

If we eliminate the language of congruences by substituting inline the below proof of the Congruence Product Rule then we obtain *exactly* the common proof given in most other answers. Even if congruences are unfamiliar, we can still impose this intuitive arithmetical structure by using the Product Rule in an equivalent *divisbility form,* namely

$$\begin{align} {\rm mod}\,\ m\!:\, A\equiv a,\, B\equiv b&\ \ \,\Longrightarrow\,\ \ AB\equiv ab\qquad\text{Congruence Product Rule}\\[3pt]
m\mid A-a,\ B-b&\,\Rightarrow\, m\mid AB-ab\qquad\text{Divisibility Product Rule}\\[4pt] 
{\bf Proof}\quad (A-\color{0a0}{a)B+a(B}&-b)\, = AB-ab\end{align}$$

Thus the inductive step *need not* be pulled out of a hat like magic. Rather, it has  intuitive *arithmetical* content as congruence multiplication. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242) for further discussion, including details showing how inlining the congruence proofs yields precisely the common unmotivated inductive proofs that are pulled out of a hat like magic.

**Note** $ $  I wrote the congruence proof in the above form (vs. simpler congruence forms) in order to better highlight how other answers are *precisely* equivalent to applying the Product Rule.  A simpler way is to use the Congruence Product and [Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) (whose proof is by induction on $n$) as below

$$\color{#c00}{9\equiv 2}\,\Rightarrow\, -3(\color{#c00}9^n)\equiv -3(\color{#c00}2^n)\equiv -3(2)2^{n-1}\equiv 2^{n-1}\qquad$$

so it boils down to $\,2^{-1}2^n\equiv 2^{n-1},\,$  since $\,2^{-1}\equiv -3$.

Comment: **Remark** $ $ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2358987/242) and its links for further examples and elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(k)=3^{2k+1}+2^{k-1}=7 \lambda (let)$$
Now, For $(k+1)$,
$$9*3^{2k+1}+2^{k-1}.2$$
Put $2^{k-1}$ form first equation i wrote
$$7.(3^{2k+1}+2\lambda)$$

Hope your doubt is solved?

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression is obviously $$3^{2n+1}+ 2^{n-1}$$.

$n=1: 3^3 +2^0 = 27 +1 =28$

$n=2: 3^5 +2^1 = 245 = (35)(7)$

$n=3: 3^7 +2^2 = 2191 = (313)(7)$

So

```
 3^[2(n+1)+1] +2^(n+1-1) = [3^(2n+1)](9) + 2^n

                    = [7k-2^(n-1)](9) +2^n

                    = 63k -2^(n-1)(9-2)

                    = (7)[9k - 2^(n-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

By the binomial theorem
$$
3^{2n+1}=3\cdot 9^n=3(7+2)^n=3(7a+2^n)=21a+6\cdot2^{n-1}
$$
Therefore
$$
3^{2n+1}+2^{n-1}=21a+7\cdot2^{n-1}=7(3a+2^{n-1})
$$

Comment: Induction is in the binomial theorem...