# Prove $4^{n} -1$ is divisible by $3$ for all $n\geq1$

Tags: induction, computer-science

I'm doing some homework, and can't seem to get my head around this inductive proof.

So far I have got:

Atom case:
$4^1 -1 = 3$, so proved for basic case.

Closure:

Assume $4^k - 1$ is divisible by $3$, Show that $4^{k+1} -1$ is divisible by $3$.

So: $4^k-1 = 4^k\cdot4 -1$ but this is where I get stuck, unsure where to go from here.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: $4^{k+1}-1=4^k\cdot4-1=4^k(3+1)-1=3\cdot4^k+4^k-1$

Comment: if you knew modular arithmetic ( clock math/remainder math) there's another way

Comment: Thank you @Peyton and I wish I did but sadly not!

Comment: Also, $x^{n+1}-1 = (x-1)(x^n + x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1)$ indicates that $(x-1)|(x^{n+1}-1)$ if $x>0$. Note: this is not an inductive proof and the above by @Peyton is the right hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ To induct $\rm\color{#c00}{multiply}$ the first two congruences below (using the [Congruence Product Rule)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

$$\begin{align} \bmod 3\!:\quad\ \    4&\equiv 1\\[.3em]
4^{\large n}&\equiv 1\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ P(n)\\
\overset{\color{#c00}{\rm multiply}}\Longrightarrow\ 4^{\large n+1} &\equiv 1\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \  P(n\!+\!1)
\end{align}$$

**Remark** $ $ The proof is a special case of an *inductive* proof of the [Congruence Power Rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) which is the straightforward inductive extension of the Product Rule.

If congruences  are unfamiliar then we can instead use the Product Rule in Divisibility form:

$$\begin{align} {\rm mod}\,\ m\!:\, A\equiv a,\, B\equiv b&\ \ \,\Longrightarrow\,\ \ AB\equiv ab\qquad\text{Congruence Product Rule}\\[3pt]
m\mid \color{#c00}{A-a},\ B-b&\,\Rightarrow\, m\mid \color{#0a0}{AB-ab}\qquad\text{Divisibility Product Rule}\\[4pt] 
{\bf Proof}\quad (A-a)B+a(B&-b)\, = AB-ab\end{align}$$

This way it is: $\,\ 3\,\mid\, \underbrace{4-1}_{\large \color{#c00}{A\,-\,a}},\, \underbrace{4^n-1}_{\large B\,-\,b}\,\Rightarrow\, 3\,\mid\, \underbrace{4\cdot 4^{\large n}-1\cdot 1}_{\large \color{#0a0}{AB\,-\,ab}} = 4^{\large n+1}-1$.

**Note** $ $ If you examine the common inductive proofs of this and similar results you will see that the proofs are *precisely* special cases of the above proof of the Product Rule (in either f0rm), e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242) where I explain that at length. Thus these Product Rules can be seen as the inductive essence of the matter. Bringing this innate *arithmetical* structure to the fore enables us to greatly simplify the inductive structure - so much so that the induction becomes completely obvious - boiling down to the obvious inductive proof that  $\,1^n\equiv 1$.

Answer (score 3):

For any $n\ge1$ it will be the case that exactly one of $2^n-1,2^n, 2^n+1$ will be divisible by $3$.

Since $2^n$ is not divisible by $3$ then the product $(2^n-1)(2^n+1)=4^n-1$ must be divisible by $3$.

Comment: i.e. it's $\,\color{#c00}{3\nmid a}\,\Rightarrow\,3\nmid (a\!-\!1)(a\!+\!1) = a^2\!-\!1\, $ for $\,a = 2^n.\ $ This is a special case of Fermat's littleTheorem, or $d$ divides one of a sequence of $d$ consectuive integers, etc. This reduces the problem to proving that $\,\color{#c00}{3\nmid 2^n},\,$ presumably by induction given the OP's tag.

Comment: @BillDubuque True, but I ignored the induction tag since I surmised OP thought that induction might be the best way to proceed. I thought the fundamental theorem was the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

$$
4^{k+1} - 1 = 4\cdot4^k-1 
            = 3\cdot4^k + 4^k-1.
$$

Therefore via induction we know $4^k-1$ is divisible by three, and the $3\cdot 4^{k}$ is clearly divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way: You have $4^k - 1 = 3m$, so $4^k=3m+1$. Now multiply both sides by $4$:

$$4^{k+1}=4(3m+1) = 12m+4 = 12m+3+1=3(4m+1)+1=3n+1$$

Thus, $4^{k+1}-1 = 3n$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method of induction to prove the exercise.

For $n=1$, $4^n-1=4^1-1=3$ is divisible by $3$.

For $n=k$, assume $4^k-1$ is divisible by $3$, so $4^k-1=3m$ for some integer $m$.

For $n=k+1$, $4^n-1=4^{k+1}-1=4^k.4-4+3=4.(4^k-1)+3=4.3m+3=3.(4m+1)$ which is definitely divisible by $3$.

Thus, by the method of induction, our problem is solved for all $n\ge 1$

Answer (score 0):

even though you don't know modular arithmetic, I'd add it can be done with: $4^n-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3\implies 1^n-1\equiv 0 \pmod 3\implies 0\equiv 0\pmod 3$.
Simply because the remainder of 4 on division by 3 is 1.