# Proving $7|13\cdot 6^{n}+8\cdot 13^{n}$ for all natural numbers.

Tags: proof-verification, induction, divisibility

I would like to verify whether my proof is correct. The answer sheet used a much more intuitive and logical approach but I think mine is correct also.

---

To prove:  $7|13\cdot 6^{n}+8\cdot 13^{n}$ for all natural numbers

Proof: We proceed by induction and show the base case holds.
$13+8=21 $. Since 7 divides 21 the base case holds.

We assume $7|13\cdot 6^{m}+8\cdot 13^{m}$ and we need to show $7|13\cdot6^{m+1}+8\cdot 13^{m+1}$.

Since, $7|13\cdot 6^{m}+8\cdot 13^{m}$, we have,  $13\cdot 6^{m}+8\cdot 13^{m} =7x, \space x \in \mathbb{N}$.

We rewrite $13\cdot 6^{m+1}+8\cdot 13^{m+1}$ as $6(13\cdot 6^m)+13(8\cdot 13^m)$ and notice, $13\cdot 6^m=7x-8\cdot13^m$.

We substitute and find,

$6(7x-8\cdot13^m)+13(8\cdot13^m)=42x-48\cdot13^m+104\cdot13^m = 42x+56\cdot13^m=7(6x+8\cdot13^m)$

Since $6x+8\cdot13^m \space  \in \mathbb{N}$

$\\ \therefore $ By the principle of mathematical induction,   $7|13\cdot 6^{n}+8\cdot 13^{n}$ for all natural numbers $n \space \blacksquare$.

Comment: Yes, seems correct. But note that $6\equiv -1\equiv 13$ and $8\equiv 1\pmod7$, so it's $\equiv (-1)\cdot(-1)^n+1\cdot(-1)^n\,\pmod7$.

Comment: @Berci My answer sheet used that approach. So, $7 \cdot 13 \cdot 6^m - 13 \cdot 6^m $ etc. That's what you mean by congruency right?

Comment: Must the proof use induction?  Do you know modular arithmetic or congruences and can you use them?

Comment: @BillDubuque I had to use induction but if you have time could you please answer this question how you would have done it?

Comment: @Berci for some reason I found it hard to reason about it that way because of the combination of the multiplication of numbers.

Comment: Just verify yourself that $a_1\equiv a_2,\ b_1\equiv b_2\implies a_1b_1\equiv a_2b_2\pmod m$ for arbitrary integers $a_i,b_i,m$. [$m\,|\,(a_2-a_1)b_2 + a_1(b_2-b_1)$] Everything else follows from here. (E.g. by induction, $a_1^k\equiv a_2^k \pmod m$ then, etc.)

Comment: I'd say. $\!\bmod 7\!:\ \color{#c00}{13}\equiv 6\,\Rightarrow\, 13\cdot 6^n + 8\cdot \color{#c00}{13}^n\equiv  21\cdot 6^n\equiv 0\cdot 6^n.\ $ In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242) I carefully explain the realtionship between the congruence and inductive proofs.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you!

Comment: @Berci Thank you!

Comment: @Cro-Magnon I added an answer that should prove enlightening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your comment, we simplify your inductive proof to highlight the relationship with congruence-based proofs. Your proof can be viewed as scaling by $\color{#c00}{13 = 6+7}\,$ the  hypothesized equation $\,P(n)$

$$\begin{align} (\color{#c00}{13=6+7})\,\  {\rm times}\,\ (\overbrace{a\,13^{\large n}\ +\ \ b\,6^{\large n}\   \!=\ 7k}^{\Large P(n)})\qquad\quad&\\[.3em]
\Longrightarrow\ \ \ \underbrace{a\,13^{\large n+1} + b\,6^{\large n+1}\  =\,\  7(13k-b\,6^n)}_{\Large P(n+1)} \end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Its *arithmetical* essence is clearer $\bmod 7\,$ using congruences and the  [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

$$\begin{align} \color{#c00}{13}\,&\equiv\, \color{#c00}6\\[.3em]
\times\ \ \quad a\,13^{\large n}&\equiv -b\,6^{\large n}\quad \qquad P(n)\\[1em] 
\hline
\Rightarrow\ a\,13^{\large n+1}&\equiv -b\,6^{\large n+1}\qquad P(n+1) \end{align}\quad \qquad$$

where $\,a,b = 8,13$ in your case. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242) I explain at length how the inductive proofs are nothing but special cases of the *proofs* of the Congruence Product Rule. As above, it is much clearer to use the rule as a lemma (call by *name*)  rather the repeat its proof inline (call by *value*) in the special case at hand.

Comment: I learned so much from this post. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

It is correct, but:

- When you wrote that “We rewrite $13\cdot 6^{m}+8\cdot 13^{m}$ as $6(13\cdot 6^m)+13(8\cdot 13^m)$”, what you meant was “We rewrite $13\cdot 6^{m+1}+8\cdot 13^{m+1}$ as $6(13\cdot 6^m)+13(8\cdot 13^m)$”.
- You don't need to compute $6\times8$ and $13\times8$. Note that\begin{align}6(7x-8\times13^m)+13(8\times13^m)&=7\times(6x)+(-6+13)\times(8\times13^m)\\&=7\times(6x+8\times13^m).\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! Your second point is really important but I found it hard to see and in fact didn't see it in my proof.

Answer (score 2):

$$13\cdot 6^{n}+8\cdot 13^{n}\equiv  (-1)(-1)^n+(1)(-1)^n =0 \text { mod (7) }$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $13\cdot 6^n+8\cdot 13^n$ in base $7$:
$$16\cdot 6^n+11\cdot 16^n$$

Note that $6\cdot 6=51$ in base $7$.

The first term ends with $1$ if $n$ is even and ends with $6$ if $n$ is odd. Conversely, the second term ends with $1$ if $n$ is even and ends with $6$ if $n$ is odd. Therefore, the sum ends with $0$.