# Help with induction using divisibility.

Tags: induction, divisibility

Need some help with this question for induction using divisibility: $8*19^n-2*3^{2n+2}$ is divisible by 10 for any positive integer.
What I have so far is proving the first value and $P_k$ and $P_{k+1}$

$P_1$ = $8*19^1-2*3^{2+2}$=-10; $P_1$ is true.

$P_k$ = $8*19^k-2*3^{2k+2}$= 10A

$P_{k+1}$ = $8*19^{k+1}-2*3^{2k+4}$ = 10B

I've just found myself stuck on the proof starting with:

$8*19^{k+1}-2*3^{2k+4}$=

Thanks for any help. If I could get an answer in the format of $P_k$ and $P_{k+1}$ that would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ be the statement that $10 \mid 8 \cdot 19^n - 2 \cdot 3^{2n + 2}$.

If we wish to establish that the statement holds for all nonnegative integers, we have to verify that $P(0)$ holds since that will be our base case.

Since $8 \cdot 19^0 - 2 \cdot 3^2 = 8 - 18 = -10 = 10 \cdot (-1)$, $P(0)$ holds.

If we wish to establish that the statement holds for all positive integers, we have to verify that $P(1)$ holds since that will be our base case.

Since $8 \cdot 19^1 - 2 \cdot 3^4 = 8 \cdot 19 - 2 \cdot 81 = 152 - 162 = -10 = 10 \cdot (-1)$, $P(1)$ holds.

Assume $P(k)$ holds for some positive integer $k$.  Then $10 \mid 8 \cdot 19^k - 2 \cdot 3^{2k + 2}$, so there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $8 \cdot 19^k - 2 \cdot 3^{2k + 2} = 10m$.

Let $n = k + 1$.  Then
\begin{align*}
8 \cdot 19^n - 2 \cdot 3^{2n + 2} & = 8 \cdot 19^{k + 1} - 2 \cdot 3^{2(k + 1) + 2}\\
& = 19 \cdot 8 \cdot 19^k - 2 \cdot 3^{2k + 4}\\
& = 19 \cdot 8 \cdot 19^k - 9 \cdot 2 \cdot 3^{2k + 2}\\
& = (10 + 9) \cdot 8 \cdot 19^k - 9 \cdot 2 \cdot 3^{2k + 2}\\
& = 10 \cdot 8 \cdot 19^k + 9(8 \cdot 19^k - 2 \cdot 3^{2k + 2})\\
& = 10 \cdot 8 \cdot 19^k + 9 \cdot 10m && \text{by the induction hypothesis}\\
& = 10(8 \cdot 19^k + 9m)
\end{align*}
Thus, if $10 \mid 8 \cdot 19^k - 2 \cdot 3^{2k + 2}$, $10 \mid 8 \cdot 19^{k + 1} - 2 \cdot 3^{2(k + 1) + 2}$.  Hence, $P(k) \implies P(k + 1)$.

Since $P(1)$ holds and $P(k) \implies P(k + 1)$ for each $k \geq 1$, $P(n)$ holds for each positive integer $n$.  The same steps that establish $P(k) \implies P(k + 1)$ also apply when $k$ is a nonnegative integer.

In fact, since $P(0)$ holds, $P(1)$ holds, and $P(k) \implies P(k + 1)$ for each $k \geq 1$, $P(n)$ holds for each nonnegative integer $n$.

Had we wished to prove that $P(n)$ holds for each nonnegative integer $n$, we could have skipped the step of establishing that $P(1)$ holds and instead assumed that $P(k)$ holds for some nonnegative integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it works for non-negative integers $n$. Let $u_n:=8\times 19^n-2\times 9^{n+1}$ so $u_0=-10$ and $u_{k+1}-9u_k=80\times 19^k$, so $10|u_0$ and $10|u_k\implies 10|u_{k+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm new to induction how would this answer be included using the terms of $P_{k+1}$ and $P_{k}$

Comment: @JoshuaCridland You could define $P_k$ as $10|u_k$.

Answer (score 0):

*Conceptually* the inductive step follows very simply by *multiplying* the first two congruences below using  CPR = [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), $ $

$$\begin{align}\bmod 10\!:\qquad\ \ \  \color{#c00}{19}\ &\equiv\ \color{#c00}{9}\\[.2em]
{\rm times}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 8\cdot 19^{\large n}&\equiv 18\cdot 9^{\large n}\quad\ \ \ \ \ P(n)_{\phantom{|}}\\[.2em]
\hline
\Longrightarrow\ \ 8\cdot 19^{\large n+\color{#c00}1}&\equiv 18\cdot 9^{\large n+\color{#c00}1}\quad\ P(n\!+\!\color{#c00}1),
\ \ \rm by \ CPR^{\phantom{|^|}}\end{align}\qquad  $$

i.e. the proof is a special case of the  (inductive) proof of the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). Note how the use of congruences  highlights innate *arithmetical* structure allowing us to reduce the induction to an easy one $\,a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, a^n\equiv b^n,\,$ with *obvious* inductive step: multiply by $\,a\equiv b\,$ via the product rule.

**Remark** $ $  If you don't know congruences we can preserve this *arithmetical* essence by using an analogous *product rule* for *divisibility* (DPR), as explained [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3178208/242)

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2949188/242) for a similar example done with and without congruences.