# $8^n-3^n$ Divisible by 5 - Proof Verification.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, divisibility

Statement: $\frac{8^k-3^k}{5}=M, M\in\mathbb{N}$

Base case: $P(1): \frac{8-3}{5}=1\in\mathbb{N}$

Assume $P(n): \frac{8^n-3^n}{5}=N$

Then, $P(n+1)=8^{n+1}-3^{n+1}=5K$, where $K$ is in terms of $M$

Writing LHS in terms of $N$:

$8^n-3^n=5N \to 8\cdot8^n-8*3^n=40N$

$8^{n+1}-3^{n+1}=40M+5\cdot3^{n+1}$

Dividing through by $5$:

$\frac{8^{n+1}-3^{n+1}}{5}=8M+3^{n+1}=K$
, where $K$ is clearly an integer, as $M$ and $N$ Are defined to be integers.

———————————————————————————————

Questions:

1. Is this proof valid?
2. Adding to that, is that last deduction of $K\in\mathbb{N}$ fair?

Comment: $8^n-3^n=(5+3)^n-3^n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i}5^{i}3^{n-i}=5\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i}5^{i-1}3^{n-i}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.  Below I explain how to view the *arithmetical* essence of the matter more conceptually as the result of a **product rule**, first using congruences, and later using bare divisibility (in case you don't know congruences).

*Conceptually* the induction follows very simply by *multiplying* the first two congruences below using  CPR = [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), $ $

$$\begin{align}\bmod 5\!:\qquad \color{#c00}{8}\ &\equiv\ \color{#c00}{3}\\
8^{\large n}&\equiv 3^{\large n}\quad\ \ \ P(n)\\
\Rightarrow\ \ \color{#c00}{8}\,8^{\large n}&\equiv 3^{\large n}\color{#c00}{3}\quad\ P(n\!+\!1),\ \ \rm by \ CPR\end{align}\qquad  $$

i.e. the proof is a special case of the  (inductive) proof of the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). Note how the use of congruences  highlights innate *arithmetical* structure allowing us to reduce the induction to an easy one $\,a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, a^n\equiv b^n,\,$ with *obvious* inductive step: multiply by $\,a\equiv b\,$ via the product rule.

If you don't know congruences we can preserve this *arithmetical* essence by using an analogous *divisibility product rule*  (DPR), $ $ where  $\ m\mid n\ $ means $\,m\,$ divides $\,n,\,$ namely

$\!\!\begin{align}
5&\mid\  \color{#c00}{8\,\ \ -\  3}\\
5&\mid\ \  \ 8^{\large n} -\ 3^{\large n}\quad\ P(n)\\
\Rightarrow\ \ 5&\mid\ \color{#c00}{8}8^{n}\! -\!\color{#c00}33^{\large n}\quad\ \ P(n\!+\!1),\ \ \rm by\ the\ rule\ below\\[.8em]
{\bf Divisibility\ Product\ Rule}\ \ \ \  
m&\mid\  a\ -\ b\qquad {\rm i.e.}\quad \   a\,\equiv\, b\\
m&\mid \ \ A\: -\: B\qquad\qquad \ A\,\equiv\, B\\
\Rightarrow\ \ m&\mid aA - bB\quad  \Rightarrow\quad aA\equiv bB\!\pmod{\!m}\\[.4em]
{\bf Proof}\,\ \   m\mid (\color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b})A + b(\color{#0a0}{A\!-\!B}) \ \ \ &\!\!\!\!=\, aA-bB\ \ \text{by $\,m\,$ divides $\rm\color{#0a0}{green}$ terms by hypothesis.}\end{align}$

**Remark** $ $ The proof in Jose's answer is nothing but a (numerical) special case of the prior proof - [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242) where I explain that at length. Further discussion on related topics is in  [many prior posts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a242%20%22divisibility%20product%20rule%22)

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is correct. I suggest that you use $\implies$ instead of $\rightarrow$ in your proofs. Besides, it would have beeen simpler if you had written\begin{align}8^{n+1}-3^{n+1}&=8\times8^n-8\times3^n+8\times3^n-3^{n+1}\\&=8\times(8^n-3^n)+5\times3^n.\end{align}

Comment: The (unmotivated) proof above is  a special case of the proof of the Congruence (or Divisibility) **Product Rule**, and the proof is much more simple and natural when presented that way, as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that if $$8\equiv 3\mod 5$$ then $$8^n\equiv 3^n\mod 5$$