# Prove (by induction) For n $\in \mathbf{N}\ 13^{n+1} − 7^n$ is divisible by 6

Tags: induction, divisibility

I started with:
$n=0: 13^{0+1} - 7^0 = 13-1 = 12$ divisible by 6.
$n=1: 13^{1+1} - 7^1 = 162 $ divisible by 6.
$13^{n+1} − 7^n = 6*k$ for any $k \in  \mathbf{N}$
$n \longrightarrow n+1:$
\begin{align*}
    13^{(n+1)+1} − 7^{n+1} &= 13^{n+2} − 7^{n+1}\\
    &= 13^{n+2} − 7^{n+1}
\end{align*}

However this is where i'm stuck.

Comment: Simplify $(13^{n+2}-7^{n+1})-(13^{n+1}-7^n)$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242) in the dupe for how to derive such inductive proofs in an intuitive *arithmetical* way - making the proof very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint: You may write down $13=6+7$ and use the fact that $6\cdot k$ is divisible by $6$ for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.**

The solution is as follows, $13^{n+2}-7^{n+1}=13\cdot 13^{n+1}-7\cdot 7^n=(6+7)\cdot 13^{n+1}-7\cdot 7^n=6\cdot 13^{n+1}+7(13^{n+1}-7^n)$. The last expression is divisible by $6$ by the induction hypothesis.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242) for the *arithmetical* intuition behind such inductive proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Since $13=1 \mod 6$ and $7=1 \mod 6 $  we have that
$13^n-7^n=0 \mod 6$