# Proving that $|xy| = |x| + |y|$ being $x$ and $y$ two strings

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, induction

I am to prove that being $x$ a string and $|x|$ its length, one should have the following property hold true for any two strings $x$ and $y$:

$$ |xy| = |x| + |y| $$

with $x, y \in \Sigma^*$.

To prove this, I am expected to make use of the following two definitions:

1. for $x=\epsilon$ we have $|x|=0$
2. for $x=au$, being $u \in \Sigma^*$ and $a \in \Sigma$ we have $|x|=1+|u|$

Intuitively it is easy to understand what is being asked here. The idea is to prove that the length of the concatenation of any two strings is equal to the sum of their individual lenghts.

What I am failing to realise is how to tackle the problem. Should I make use of induction? Just algebraic manipulation?

Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: Induction over $|x|$ seems indicated.

Comment: Induction should work. For instance, use induction on $|y|$.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I did it. I will now post an answer on this.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, please say so. Could this be solved by observing that string concatenation is a monoid with $\epsilon$ as the identity and $|\cdot|$ mapping to integers with $+$ as operation and $0$ as identity?

Comment: Well, I am studying this in my spare time and found some exercises on this on the net. So I guess yes, they are homework. And no, I do not gain anything by having someone do it for me. I know nothing about monoids.

Comment: @devoured elysium Fair enough. As others have suggested, induction will be the easiest way. Observe that $y = \epsilon$ or $y=u$ or $y=y'u$.

Comment: @Myself @Christian To make your induction work, one needs a different property than the property 2 the OP wrote.

Comment: @Didier Piau: Agreed, it only works on the left with the property as stated. But it's probably more elegant to expand (2) into "if $x = a_1\dots a_\ell$ with $a_i\in\Sigma$ then $|x| = \ell$", with induction. From there, it's obvious that $|xy| = |a_1\dots a_\ell b_1\dots b_m| = \ell + m = |a_1\dots a_\ell| + |b_1\dots b_m| = |x| + |y|$.

Comment: I had no idea what to tag this. Feel free to change it. But please don't use proof or proof-strategy.

Comment: For a nice writeup on how induction works and how to write an inductive proof, you might see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488

Comment: @devoured elysium: What you really need here is an explicit definition of $\Sigma^*$ in order to set up the induction. Could you please give that?

Comment: @Didier Pau: Actually, I disagree. For the very definition of $|\cdot|$ to make sense, it must either be the case that $\Sigma^*$ is defined recursiively or that certain properties about $\Sigma^*$, which are unspoken here, have been established; otherwise, it is not even clear that we can talk about $|x|$ for an arbitrary $x\in\Sigma^*$. And if $\Sigma^*$ is defined recursively, then it makes more sense to do induction on the *recursive levels* of $\Sigma^*$.

Comment: @Arturo Are you sure your comment adresses anything at all that I wrote? You could explain what exactly in it you disagree with. For me, trying to understand your rather strange intervention here, I read your own recent answer. My opinion is that it is almost completely off topic (see my comment to it), the very last part excepted... where, ironically, you follow my advice to use an induction over $|x|$. :-) [But next time, please try to write my name correctly. Thanks in advance.]

Comment: @Didier: I'm not using induction on $|x|$, I'm using induction on the "layer" of $\Sigma$. You would have to prove that $x\in\Sigma^n$ if and only if $|x|=n$ to say the induction is over $|x|$, and while that can be done (by induction), it's not the same thing.

Comment: @Arturo Not an induction on $|x|$? Really?? Reread the inductive step of your own post... And I have no clue about what is *the layer of $\Sigma$*. But maybe we could leave all this, the subject being not so fascinating (to me).

Comment: @Didier: Yes, really. In order to do induction on $|x|$ I would have to argue that **if** $|x|=0$, **then** $x=\epsilon$; this is the *converse* of the definition of $|x|$, so I would have to **prove** this. And I would have to argue that **if** $|x|=n+1$, **then** I can write $x$ as $x=av$ with $a\in\Sigma$ and $u$ satisfying $|u|=n$. Again, this is not the definition of $|\cdot|$, but the **converse** of the definition. It would have to be proven.

Comment: @Didier: (cont) By "layer" I mean that you can view $\Sigma^*$ as a union of sets, the $k$-th set being $\Sigma^k$. This is the $k$th layer. I'm doing induction on $k$. I do **not** assume that if $x\in\Sigma^k$, then $|x|=k$. I only assume that if $x\in\Sigma^k$, then $|xy| = |x|+|y|$. The inductive step uses only the *definitions* of $\Sigma^{k+1}$ and of $|\cdot|$, and not any derived properties like the converse of the definition. I do not assume *anything* about $|x|$ or $|u|$, except what is in the definitions. It's not induction on $|x|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19370/demonstration-by-induction-1an-1an/19377#19377) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) for general advice and discussion on induction. Your argument above is, alas, neither very clear nor correct.

So, we have that $|\epsilon|=0$, and that if $x=au$ with $a\in\Sigma$, $u\in\Sigma^*$, then $|x|=1+|u|$. We want to prove that for all $x,y\in\Sigma^*$, we have $|xy|=|x|+|y|$.

What you *really* need here is an explicit definition of $\Sigma^*$, because you need to be able to handle elements of $\Sigma^*$. I'm guessing, pending you posting the definition, that you have a certain "alphabet" $\Sigma$, and then define $\Sigma^*$ as the collection of all strings of letters from $\Sigma$ in some way.

Assuming the intended definition is the definition [in this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29), we can proceed as follows.

> For all $n$, if $y\in \Sigma^*$ and $x\in\Sigma^n$, then $|xy|=|x|+|y|$.

If we can prove this, it will follow that for all $x$ in $\cup\Sigma^n = \Sigma^*$, we have $|xy|=|x|+|y|$, which is what we want to prove.

We will prove the proposition above by induction on $n$.

**Base.** $n=0$. Let $x\in\Sigma^0$. Then $x=\epsilon$, so $xy = y$ and $|x|=0$ by definition of $|\epsilon|$. Therefore, $|xy|=|y|=0+|y| = |x|+|y|$, so the equality holds.

**Inductive step.** We want to prove that **if** it is true that for all $z\in \Sigma^k$, $|zy|=|z|+|y|$, **then** it is true that for all $x\in\Sigma^{k+1}$, we also have $|xy|=|x|+|y|$.

*Induction hypothesis.* If $z\in\Sigma^k$, then $|zy|=|z|+|y|$.

Let $x\in\Sigma^{k+1}$. We want to prove that $|xy|=|x|+|y|$.

Since $x\in\Sigma^{k+1}$, then $x=au$ with $a\in\Sigma$ and $u\in\Sigma^k$.

Then we have by the definition of $|\cdot|$ that 
$$|xy| = |(au)y| = |a(uy)| = 1 + |uy|.$$
And by the Induction Hypothesis, since $|u|\in\Sigma^k$, we get
$$|xy| = 1+|uy| = 1+(|u|+|y|) = (1+|u|)+|y|.$$
But by the definition of $|\cdot|$ we have $|x| = |au| = 1+|u|$, so
$$|xy| = (1+|u|)+|y| = |x|+|y|,$$
as desired.

Thus, **if** for every $z\in\Sigma^k$ we have $|zy|=|z|+|y|$, **then** for every $x\in\Sigma^{k+1}$ we have $|xy|=|x|+|y|$.

By induction, we conclude that for all $n$, if $x\in\Sigma^n$ then $|xy|=|x|+|y|$.

Therefore, we have that for all $x\in\mathop{\cup}\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\Sigma^n$, $|xy| = |x|+|y|$.

Thus, for all $x\in \Sigma^*$, $|xy|=|x|+|y|$.

Since $y\in\Sigma^*$ is arbitrary, we conclude that

> For all $x,y\in \Sigma^*$, $|xy|= |x|+|y|$

as claimed. **QED**

Comment: @Arturo If I understand your post correctly, the first two thirds are off topic. Simply put, there is no problem at all with the definitions of $\Sigma^*$ and of $|x|$ for $x$ in $\Sigma^*$. This is basic stuff of the field, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29 for example (so I would not blame the OP for such an omission). In fact, one can forget all this top-down and bottom-up stuff (and I am not sure you really meant to write *bottoms-up* here...) and your recursive definition of $\Sigma^*$. .../...

Comment: .../... Instead, why not use the classical Cartesian products $\Sigma^n$ for every positive integer $n$ (and not your sets $\Sigma_n$), as everybody else does? This would simplify the only relevant part of your post (the last third, where you perform the proof by induction that I hinted at one month ago, following exactly the way I explained then), where your $\Sigma_n$ sets only complicate things.

Comment: @Didier: I don't know what definition of $\Sigma^*$ the OP has, or what properties he knows. If the definition is via the bottoms up approach and this is standard and assumed,, then yes, you can drop the entire first part and jump until the last part. The $\Sigma_n$ I defined are simply equal to $\cup_{i=1}^n\Sigma^n$ as per the definition in the Wikipedia page, though, so I don't see how they "complicate things"...

Comment: @Arturo The so called Kleene closure $\Sigma^*$ of $\Sigma$ is by definition the union of the $\Sigma^n$, each Cartesian product $\Sigma^n$ is by definition the set of functions from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to $\Sigma$. You still need to know how to compose a function from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to $\Sigma$ with a function from $\{1,2,...,k\}$ to $\Sigma$, to produce a function from $\{1,2,...,n+k\}$ to $\Sigma$ (a not too difficult task), et voilà! No recursion. No bottom-up approach. Sorry to insist, but this is really basic stuff and yes, everybody defines $\Sigma^*$ in this way.

Comment: @Didier: Yes, I know this is basic and easy. *I* could do it in my sleep and with one hand tied behind my back. And behind everything you say, there is an application of the recursion theorem which perhaps you aren't seeing. And yet, it's there.

Comment: @Didier: P.S. I've actually seen *both* definitions, the bottoms-up (the one in the link), and the top-down definition, given in the literature, depending on the intended audience. So, no, not "everybody" defines it the same way.

Comment: @Arturo Once again: WP uses a definition that is neither bottom-up neither top-down, WP defines $\Sigma^*$ "all at once", without any recursion, and many people proceed likewise. If it is important to you to proceed otherwise, fine. You wisely dropped the ugly sets $\Sigma_n$ and the first two thirds of the previous version of your answer, and for that I wish to congratulate you. Enough for me.

Comment: @Didier: Read the WP article on "Kleene closure". You will see that it defines **precisely** in the top-down approach that I gave in the first part: as the "smallest superset of $\Sigma$ that contains the empty string and is closed under string concatenation." Thus, you are incorrect in claiming that the definition is "neither neither bottom-up [nor] top-down". It's **top-down.** It immediately establishes the equality with the **bottom-up** approach by describing the Kleene closure as a union of $\Sigma_n$s. So, again, just because **you** don't notice them doesn't mean they're not there.

Comment: @Didier: The second definition of the Kleene closure/ Kleene star given in WP is, likewise, **precisely** the "bottom up" approach I gave, using **precisely** the sets $\Sigma_n$, which are defined **recursively**. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star . Since WP invokes the Kleene star in its *formal* definition of $\Sigma^*$ (as opposed to the informal definition as "all strings"), the definition is only "all at once" if you choose to ignore the meaning of "Kleene star", or if you choose to think that an informal definition is a substitute for a mathematical one.

Answer (score 1):

I have upvoted Arturo Magidin's answer. But aren't we shooting with cannons on sparrows here? A fundamental principle of counting is that it is additive on disjoint sets. Now count the number of cells that are occupied by your strings.

Answer (score 0):

So, I will only cover here how to solve this for the inductive step, as the other is rather easy (not that the inductive step one isn't!).

Considering a string $x'=\lambda x$ we have

$$\begin{align}
|x'y| &= |x'|+|y| \\
|\lambda xy| &= |\lambda x| + |y| \\
|\lambda z| &= 1 + |x| + |y| \\
1 + |z| &= 1 + |x| + |y| \\
1+|xy| &= 1 + |xy|
\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry to be blunt but this is not a proof. Not nearly. A proof by induction begins with stating precisely an induction hypothesis $H_n$. Then one proves that $H_1$ holds (for instance). Then one proves that, for every $n\ge1$, if $H_n$ holds, then $H_{n+1}$ holds. If you do all this, you won in the sense that you proved that $H_n$ holds for every $n\ge1$.

Comment: as stated above, this is the inductive step (Hn+1).

Comment: The inductive step is not to prove that $H_n$ holds nor to prove that $H_{n+1}$ holds. The inductive step is to prove that if $H_n$ holds then $H_{n+1}$ holds. For example, consider for $H_n$ the assertion that the sum of the powers of $2$ from $2^0=1$ to $2^n$ is $2^{n+1}+7$. Then, for every nonegative $n$, $H_n$ does imply $H_{n+1}$ even though every $H_n$ is false.

Comment: If you want, you can show us noobs how to do it right as a separate answer (and have the 15 points, as although several people helped me understand the problem, they only did it as comments!).

Comment: OK (but next time you could spare us this *us noobs* thing). As I said, *A proof by induction begins with stating precisely an induction hypothesis $H_n$*, so what is your $H_n$? Hint: the answer is in my first comment to your post.