# Complete induction of $10^n \equiv (-1)^n \pmod{11}$

Tags: induction

To prove $10^n \equiv (-1)^n\pmod{11}$, $n\geq 0$, I started an induction.

It's $$11|((-1)^n - 10^n) \Longrightarrow (-1)^n -10^n = k*11,\quad k \in \mathbb{Z}. $$

For $n = 0$:
$$ (-1)^0 - (10)^0 = 0*11 $$

$n\Rightarrow n+1$
$$\begin{align*}
 (-1) ^{n+1} - (10) ^{n+1} &= k*11\\
(-1)*(-1)^n - 10*(10)^n &= k*11
\end{align*}$$
But I don't get the next step.

Answer (score 11):

You are not setting up your induction very well. You **should not** start with the equality you want to establish, namely that $(-1)^{n+1}-10^{n+1}$ is a multiple of $11$. Instead, you should start with the *Induction Hypothesis*, which is that $(-1)^n - 10^n$ is a multiple of $11$.

So: the *Inductive Step* is to show that **if** $(-1)^n - 10^n$ is a multiple of $11$, **then** $(-1)^{n+1} - 10^{n+1}$ is also a multiple of $11$.

Let's write out our Induction Hypothesis: it says that
$$\text{There exists an integer }k\text{ such that }(-1)^n - 10^n = 11k.$$

What we want to prove is that:
$$\text{there exists an integer }\ell\text{ such that }(-1)^{n+1}-10^{n+1}=11\ell.$$
(Note that the multiple may be different, that's why I used a different letter).

So now we can try manipulating the expression we want. One possibility is to use the following identity:
$$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1} = (a-b)(a^n + a^{n-1}b + a^{n-2}b^2 + \cdots + ab^{n-1}+b^n),$$
if you already know this identity.

So we have, with $a=-1$ and $b=10$,
$$
(-1)^{n+1} - 10^{n+1} = \Bigl( (-1) - 10\Bigr)\Bigl( (-1)^n + (-1)^{n-1}(10) + \cdots + (-1)10^{n-1} + 10^n\Bigr).$$
Now notice that you don't even need to use the induction hypothesis to conclude that $(-1)^{n+1}-10^{n+1}$ is a multiple of $11$ (as could be seen in mac's answer).

If you don't know the identity, then you can perform some purely algebraic manipulations. E.g.,
$$\begin{align*}
(-1)^{n+1} - 10^{n+1} &= -1\left( (-1)^n + 10^{n+1}\right)\\
 &= -\left( (-1)^n -10^n + 10^n + 10^{n+1}\right)\\
&= -\left( \Bigl((-1)^n - 10^n\Bigr) + 10^n\Bigl(1 + 10\Bigr)\right)\\
&= -\left( 11k + 10^n(11)\right) &\quad&\text{(by the induction hypothesis)}\\
&= -\left( 11(k+10^n)\right)\\
&= 11\left( -(k+10^n)\right),
\end{align*}$$
which gives that $(-1)^{n+1} - 10^{n+1}$ is a multiple of $11$, as desired, from the assumption that $(-1)^n - 10^n$ is a multiple of $11$.

---

But easier still is to use the following property of congruences:

**Proposition.** Let $a,b,c,d,k$ be integers. If 
$$a\equiv b\pmod{k}\qquad\text{and}\qquad c\equiv d\pmod{k}$$
then $ac\equiv bd\pmod{k}$.

*Proof.* Since $a\equiv b\pmod{k}$, then $k|a-b$, so $k$ divides any multiple of $a-b$; for example, $k|(a-b)c = ac-bc$. Since $k$ divides $ac-bc$, then $ac\equiv bc\pmod{k}$.

Since $c\equiv d\pmod{k}$, then $k|c-d$, so $k|(c-d)b = cb-db$, hence $bc\equiv bd\pmod{k}$.

Since $ac\equiv bc\pmod{k}$ and $bc\equiv bd\pmod{k}$, then $ac\equiv bd\pmod{k}$. **QED**

**Corollary.** If $a_1\equiv b_1\pmod{k}$, $a_2\equiv b_2\pmod{k},\ldots, a_n\equiv b_n\pmod{k}$, then 
$$a_1\cdots a_n\equiv b_1\cdots b_n\pmod{k}.$$

*Proof.* Induction on $n$. **QED**

(This is where you would want to use induction, rather than the specific case you are looking at).

**Corollary.** If $a\equiv b\pmod{k}$, then for all positive integers $n$, $a^n\equiv b^n\pmod{k}$.

*Proof.* Apply previous corollary with $a_i=a$ and $b_i=b$ for all $i$. **QED**

Comment: @Arturo One needs to be careful here. The first proof could well be circular. You are apparently implicitly assuming the result that for all $\rm\:n\:$ one has $\rm\ a-b\ |\ a^n - b^n\ $ in $\rm\:\mathbb Z[a,b]\:,\:$ which is *stronger* than the result desired and, moreover, *it* requires an (inductive) proof itself (at this level). One could perhaps work around this if it could be deduced as a special case of some more general known result, such as the Factor Theorem $\rm\:x-y\ |\ f(x)-f(y)\:,\:$ but I don't see any mention of such above, nor is it clear that the OP has access to such.

Comment: @Bill: Technically, I'm asserting an equality between $a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}$ and $(a-b)(a^n + a^{n-1}b+\cdots+ab^{n}+b^{n+1})$, which implies the divisibility statement you say I am "implicitly assuming"; I grant that I'm not *proving* that assertion (which can be done by induction), but seems somewhat askew to say I'm "implicitly assuming" a result when I am *explicitly* saying what I'm using.

Comment: @Arturo: If you're assuming that (*much* stronger) result without proof then the proof is circular in my opinion. Moreover, I don't think it is good from a pedagogical standpoint to manipulate expressions involving '$\:\ldots\:$' when teaching inductive proofs. The whole point of *mathematical* induction is to eliminate such nonrigorous inductive informalities in favor of objects with more rigorous syntax and semantics.

Comment: @Bill: I am well aware that your geometric notions and mine don't agree.

Comment: @Bill: You missed the joke. I'm well aware that what I consider "circular" and what *you* consider "circular" (i.e., "geometric notions") are not the same thing. I'm also well aware that you often call things I do "circular" on the basis of what you consider to be "previous", "stronger", etc., and that I don't always agree. But, please, do go ahead expressing how disappointed you are; it's not my goal to please you.

Comment: @Arturo Well if that's your idea of how to teach induction then I'm afraid we are worlds apart on pedagogical matters. But of course that wouldn't be the first time that has occurred. My jaw drops when I see experienced mathematicians commit such serious pedagogical errors.

Comment: @Bill: Frankly, to care less about where your jaw is at any given moment would take a lot more effort than I'm willing to expend at this moment. Your efforts to "correct me" are, at this point, wholly counterproductive, in case you hadn't noticed.

Comment: @Bill: And, of course, for *daring* to not care about your opinion. Though you will now go on to sputtering about how this is not the case. Enjoy. As to what my idea is of "how to teach induction", [false implies anything](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19370/demonstration-by-induction-1an-1an/19377#19377).

Comment: @Arturo I don't see the point of that link (another joke?). The reason I emphasize this point is that I've seen many students fall victim to such circular proofs. Most likely what you meant wasn't circular, but it was not communicated clearly above. Many students could interpret it in a circular way, and go on to give analogous circular proofs. Why not simply clarify what you intended so to avoid such issues?

Comment: @Bill: The link is an example of a post in which I go to some length about how I *actually* teach induction. Now, you seem to think that a proof is "circular" as soon as it uses something which you deem to be "stronger" (by your lights). Since every proof is based on axioms, and the axioms are necessarily "stronger" than any particular result (since they imply not only *that* results, but *all other* results in the theory), I wonder at how *any* proof manages to not be "circular." No, don't bother explaining; save yourself the typing.

Comment: @Arturo I'm sure you can see that the instance of the factor theorem that you employ trivially implies the desired result. By invoking it, one is essentially trading off the induction in the sought proof for an inductive proof of a more general result (perhaps already proved). There's nothing wrong with that if one *explicitly* states that is what is being done. In fact I often do so myself. But it is essential to make it clear to students that the stronger statement still requires (inductive) proof. If you had made that clear above then we would not be having this discussion.

Comment: @Bill I doubt there was anything short of writing things exactly the way you want them to be written that would have prevented you from criticising or complaining.

Comment: @Arturo As I said, obviously we disagree on fundamental pedagogical matters. The fact that you refuse to take such matters seriously but, instead, reply with 'jokes' is rather sad.

Comment: @Bill: Indeed we do; for example, you think you are being quite pedagogical with your comments; I usually find you to be rather pejorative, demeaning, and dismissive; I'm not the only one that you have, from time to time, offended with your actions that you always describe as "well-meaning", and you *invariably* attribute such disagreements to misunderstanding, misinterpretation (either accidental or willful) on your interlocutor. Here, you take the fact that we disagree, and consider it a terrible outcome that I don't come around to your point of view. But I'm sure it's all my fault, again.

Comment: @Bill. If you've ever tried anything other than your standard overbearing manner, I missed it; you don't offer "constructive advice", you chide and reprehend. But it's *always* everybody else's fault, never yours. As you say, whatever.

Comment: @Arturo Please go back and read my first comment. I see no "chiding" nor any "reprehending". By the way, I'm glad to see that you inserted "if you already know it". It'd be helpful to say a bit more, e.g. "if you've already *rigorously proved* this more general result (by induction on n) then your can invoke the special case ..."

Comment: @Arturo I saved you the trouble and explained the issues at length in another answer. Of course you are more than welcome to reference it should you so desire.

Comment: @Bill: Insertion that you are "glad to see" occurred: 18:46. Downvote occurred: 19:09. Anything short of unconditional surrender to and gracious praise of your position in any matter (including those of opinion) is chalked up to a failure of character and/or intellect: timeless.

Comment: @Arturo I did not see any of your edits till I made that remark at 20:57, since the software does not notify one of edits to an answer while one is engaged in a discussion in the comments. I was not expecting to see any changes based on your comments.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use induction you assume that $(-1)^n-10^n=11k$  Then you want to prove $(-1)^{(n+1)}-10^{(n+1)}=11m$.  So $(-1)^{(n+1)}-10^{(n+1)}=-1(-1)^n-10(10^n)=-1(11k+10^n)-10(10^n)=-11k-11(10^n)=11m$

Answer (score 3):

Since 10 ≡ -1 (mod 11), you can just raise both sides to the power of $n$.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking something similar to this, but what's the mathematical explanation for that?

Comment: Well, $$a_1\equiv b_1\pmod k,\quad a_2\equiv b_2\pmod k\implies a_1a_2\equiv b_1b_2\pmod k.$$ So by (a very easy) induction on $n$, $a\equiv b\pmod k\implies a^n\equiv b^n\pmod k$. The proof of the implication above isn't so hard: the hypothesis is the same as $k|a_1-b_1$ and $k|a_2-b_2$, hence $k|(a_1-b_1)a_2+b_1(a_2-b_2)=a_1a_2-b_ab_2$.

Comment: @Igor: The explanation is that if $k$ divides $a-b$, then $k$ divides $(a-b)c = ac-bc$, so from $a\equiv b\pmod{k}$ you can conclude that $ac\equiv bc\pmod{k}$. Starting from $x\equiv y\pmod{k}$ and $z\equiv w\pmod{k}$, multiplying both sides of $x\equiv y\pmod{k}$ by $z$ we get the valie $xz\equiv yz\pmod{k}$. Multiplying both sides of $z\equiv w\pmod{k}$ by $y$ we get $zy\equiv wy\pmod{k}$. Putting the two together, we get $xz\equiv yz\equiv yw\pmod{k}$. So if $x\equiv y\pmod{k}$ and $z\equiv w\pmod{k}$, then $xz\equiv yw\pmod{k}$ (that is, you can multiply congruences).

Comment: Hm, I can't seem to correct my earlier comment any more. It should be $b_1$, not $b_a$ at the end.

Comment: @Igor The "mathematical explanation" is the **congruence product rule** - see my answer. Or, more generally, that the set of congruence classes comprise a ring $\rm\:\mathbb Z/11 = \mathbb Z\ (mod\ 11)\:.$

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try this: $10 \equiv -1 \ (\text{mod} \ 11) \Longrightarrow (10)^{n} \equiv (-1)^{n} \ (\text{mod} \ 11)$

- And for using induction assume it's clear that for $n=1$, the result holds. Now assume that is true for $n=k$. That is $(10)^{k} \equiv (-1)^{k} \ (\text{mod} \ 11)$, and prove it for $n=k+1$.

Answer (score 3):

If $a \equiv b \left(\bmod m \right)$, then $a^n \equiv b^n \left(\bmod m \right)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,b,m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The reason being $a^n - b^n$ factors as $(a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + a^{n-3}b^2 + \cdots + b^{n-1})$ and hence if $m | (a-b)$, $m | (a^n-b^n)$

If you want to prove by induction, first note that

if $a \equiv b \left(\bmod m \right)$ and $c \equiv d \left(\bmod m \right)$, then $a \times c  \equiv b \times d \left(\bmod m \right)$.

This is true since $ac-bd = a(c-d) + d(a-b)$

Hence at the inductive step, if you have that $10^k \equiv (-1)^k \left(\bmod m \right)$, and we have that $10 \equiv (-1) \left(\bmod m \right)$ and from the above result we have
$$10^{k+1} \equiv (-1)^{k+1} \left(\bmod m \right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Below are some general remarks on inductive proofs that are too long for comments. The primary point that I'd like to emphasize is that when you are first learning how to present rigorous proofs by mathematical induction it is important to be careful to avoid composing circular proofs. Let's consider a specific example. In another answer here a proof of the desired result, that $\rm\ 10^n\equiv (-1)^n\ (mod\ 11)\:,\:$ was proposed based upon the following identity, which is true for all integers $\rm\:a,b\:$ and all naturals $\rm\:n\:$

$$\rm a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}\ =\ (a-b)\ (a^n + a^{n-1}b + a^{n-2}b^2 + \cdots + ab^{n-1}+b^n) $$

The sought result follows immediately upon specializing $\rm\: a = 10,\: b = -1\:$ in the above identity.

Does the above constitute a valid proof by induction of the sought result?  Probably your instructor would accept it as a valid proof if you first proved by induction said identity and then derived the sought result as a corollary, by specializing the identity as indicated above. However, if you don't already have available a rigorous proof that the above identity holds true for all $\rm\:n\:$ then it would not be correct to invoke the identity in your proof since, in effect, you would be assuming true a more general result, that itself requires a rigorous proof by induction. Even though you may have learned this identity in your prior studies, before you learned how to give rigorous inductive proofs, probably at that time you did not have available the tools to give such a rigorous proof. Perhaps you may even have learned more general results, such as the *Factor Theorem* $\rm\ x-y\ |\ f(x)-f(y)\:$ in $\rm\:\mathbb Z[x,y]\:$ for all polynomials $\rm\:f(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]\:.\:$ But this too requires a rigorous inductive proof, e.g. by induction on $\rm\: deg\ f\:.\:$

Thus if you propose to tackle an exercise on induction by "passing the inductive buck" to a more general result, be sure that you have already given a rigorous inductive proof of that result. Since the point of such exercises is to provide experience to help strengthen your inductive intuition, it is essential to experience the induction - whether in a specific form or a more general form.

Once you have gained some experience with inductive proofs it is important to introspect a bit at a meta-level - to abstract out various common patterns of induction. For example, many of my posts here emphasize the fact that many common inductive proofs are simply special cases of [telescopy](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy). By noticing this telescopic structure, one can often reduce the induction to a very trivial normalized form, e.g. to the trivial induction that $\rm\: 1^n = 1\:.\:$ Such reduction of inductive complexity frees up our mental faculties so that we can concentrate on more essential aspects of the problem.

Comment: Idea of "telescopy" sounds interesting — do you have some reference, by any chance?

Comment: @Grigory Off the top of my head I can't recall any references specific to induction. But, at the core, it's just a special case of effective algorithms for summation and solving difference equations, e.g. Google Gosper, Karr, Singer, Zeilberger, etc. There are many simple examples in my prior posts in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

Might be easier to do $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+2)$, i.e. prove it for odd and even numbers separately.

$P(1), P(2)$ are clear.

$P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+2)$:

$$10^{n+2}= 10^n*100=99*10^n+10^n \cong 10^n \cong (-1)^n \mod 11$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ The inductive step is $\rm\bmod 11\!:\ 10\equiv -1,\ 10^n\equiv (-1)^n  \Rightarrow\, 10^{n+1}\equiv (-1)^{n+1}$

This is simply a special case of the following ubiquitous rule for multiplying congruences

[Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\rm\ \ A\equiv\: a,\ B\:\equiv\: b\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ AB\equiv ab\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\ |\ A-a,\: B-b\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ m\ |\ (A-a)\ B + a\ (B-b)\ =\ AB - ab $

**Remark** $ $ If in the proof we put $\rm\,A = 10,\ b = -1,\ B = 10^n,\ b = (-1)^n\ $ then it shows

$$\rm  11\mid \underbrace{10^n\!-(-1)^n}_{\Large f_n}\Rightarrow\, 11\mid \underbrace{11(10^n)-(10^n\!-(-1)^n)}_{\textstyle (A-a)B\ +\ a(B-b)}= \underbrace{10^{n+1}\!-(-1)^{n+1}}_{\Large f_{n+1}}\qquad $$

i.e. $\rm\,11\mid f_n\Rightarrow\, 11\mid f_{n+1},\,$ which is the inductive step that is usually pulled out of a hat like magic in many proofs. But by above we see we can use math (Product Rule) vs. magic to *discover* a proof. But it is more conceptual *arithmetically* to not give a direct inductive proof using divisibility but instead proceed as in the hint using modular arithmetic and the Product Rule.

Abstracting a bit we can easily deduce the following more general

[Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\rm\ \ \color{}{A\equiv a}\ \Rightarrow\ \color{}{A^n\equiv a^n}\ \  (mod\ m)\ \ $ for all naturals $\rm\,n.$

**Remark** $ $ If congruences are not familiar then  we can still use the product rule in an equivalent divisibility form - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242), where we explain these ideas at much further length (including showing in detail how a couple posted inductive proofs are precisely special cases of the Product Rule).

You can find much further discussion of this fundamental product rule in [many of my prior posts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+congruence+%22product+rule%22) For example, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101/derivative-of-a-product-and-derivative-of-quotient-of-functions-theorem-i-dont/3178#3178) explains how the *derivative product rule* is closely related to the congruence product rule. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40118/if-ab-and-cd-then-acbd/40127#40127) which explains the relationship between arithmetic divisibility rules and subring structure. Many of these diverse topics will be unified when you learn about quotient rings, a ubiquitous prototype being the ring $\rm\:\mathbb Z/m\:$ of integers modulo $\rm\:m\:.$

Answer (score 1):

And since noone mentioned this yet, here is a direct proof.

If $n=2k$ is even we need to show that $10^n \cong 1 \mod 11$. But $10^{2k}-1=999....999$ where there are $2k$ 9's. Thus

$$10^{2k}-1= 90909090..909 *11 $$

If $n=2k+1$ is even we need to show that $10^n \cong -1 \mod 11$.

But $10^{2k+1}+1=999....9990+11$ where there are $2k$ 9's. Thus

$$10^{2k}+1= 90909090..9090 *11 +11$$

**Second direct solution**

We will prove instead that

$$(-10)^n \equiv 1 \pmod{11}

using the well known geometric formula:

$$1-10+10^2-10^3+...+(-10)^{n-1}= \frac{1-(-10)^n}{1-(-10)} \,.$$

Since the left side is an integer, the right side is an integer, which proves the claim. THis is overkill though....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need induction, as mac points out, but if you want to complete the inductive argument you started, you could do something like this:

$10^{n+1}=10\cdot 10^n\equiv(-1)\cdot(-1)^n=(-1)^{n+1} \; (\mod 11)$

Answer (score 0):

For the induction the following will be useful to show that the difference is a multiple of 11:

1. $10^0 - (-1)^0 = 1-1 = 11 \times 0$
2. $10^{n+1} - (-1)^{n+1} =  10\times (10^n -(-1)^n) -11 \times (-1)^n $, i.e. the difference between (by the inductive hypothesis that $10^n -(-1)^n$ is a multiple of 11*) a multiple of 11 and another multiple of 11.

An alternative method is

$$10^{n+1} - (-1)^{n+1} = 11 \times \sum_{i=0}^{n} 10^i(-1)^{n-i}$$

Answer (score -2):

Direct proof: $10^n=(11-1)^n=11(\dots)+(-1)^n$