# $a\mid b,c\Rightarrow a\mid bx+cy\,$ for any integers $x,y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $$a \mid b$$ and $$a \mid c$$  then $$a \mid bx+cy$$ for any integers $x$ and $y$.

Here's my proof:
$$b = ak$$
$$c = am$$

$$bx+cy = akx+amy = a(kx+my)$$

Notice that $kx+my$ is an integer.

Therefore by the fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic/Theorem of divisibility,

$$ a \mid bx+cy $$

Is there another way to prove this? How would you do this another way?

Comment: I think your way is nice enough. I especially like how you wrote Amy's name there.

Comment: There are no ways that are *essentially* different.

Comment: But you don't need to invoke the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)

Comment: @drhab Consider this: $\,S = a\Bbb Z\,$ is a subgroup of $\,\Bbb Z\,$ by the [Subgroup Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test) (i.e. $\,S\ne \emptyset\,$ is closed under subtraction). Therefore, since $\,S\,$ is a group, $\,b,c\in S\,\Rightarrow\, nb+mc\in S\,$ for all $\,n,m\in \Bbb Z.\ $ Do you consider that *essentialy* different?

Comment: @BillDubuque No. The OP notes in fact that $b$ and $c$ both belong to $a\mathbb Z$ and concludes almost directly that this leads to $nb+mc\in a\mathbb Z$. This without mentioning the concept of group, but nevertheless applying (or discovering if you wish) characteristics of a group.

Comment: More generally, see [divisibility w.r.t. a subring.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/158498/242)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it any other way.  However I would improve the write-up of the proof.

1. You say initially that $c=aj$ but after this you clearly mean that $c=am$.  You need to be consistent.
2. Your third equality sign is missing its left hand side.  It should be
   $$bx+cy=akx+amy=[\hbox{etc}]\ .$$
3. The reason for your final conclusion is nothing to do with the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, it is simply the definition of divisibility.