# Proof of even numbers, is my proof correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

i have gotten a question that sounds like this:

**• An even number, n, is characterized in that it can be written as n = 2 * m, where m is an integer. Proof (or argument as to why), once you multiply two even numbers with each other, you get an even number.**

So far i have done this , but im not sure if it is correct or if my explanation is thorough enough:

**n_1 * n_2**

**n_1 * n_2 is equal, therefore**

**n_1 = 2m_1**

**n_2 = 2m_2**

**thus:**

**n_1 * n_2 = 2m_1 * 2m_2 = 2 * 2**

**Since n_1 * n_2 = 2 * 2 m_1 m_2, n_1 * n_2 is an even number**

Comment: Everything looks fine. The first 2 lines are not necessary. You forgot $m_1m_2$ from the line before last. You could also dispense with indices by writing: $m=2p$ and $n=2q$ to start. This wouldn't change the proof, only make it simpler to read.

Comment: It is special case of $\,2\mid n\,\Rightarrow\,2\mid nm,\,$ or, more generally, that **multiples are closed under integer scaling** - see the linked dupe (more specifically see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3026250/242), which can't be added to the dupe list since it got no upvotes). There are many similar prior questions.

Comment: why do you put almost all of your text to boldface?

Comment: More generally sets of **(common) multiples are closed under addition and scalings** - a prototype of a fundamental ring-theoretic structure known as an  [ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your idea is pretty much correct, perhaps the (re)writing here is in better detail:

Let $n_1$ and $n_2$ be two even numbers such that
$$n_1 = 2m_1$$
$$n_2 = 2m_2$$
for $m_1,m_2\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then, we have
$$n_1\cdot n_2 = 2m_1\cdot 2m_2 = 2\cdot(2m_1m_2).$$
Now, let $m=2m_1m_2$ and observe that $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, we have
$$n_1\cdot n_2 = 2m.$$
Thus, by the definition of an even integer, $n_1\cdot n_2$ is even.

Also, as a small reminder, it's generally easier for readers / answerers to read your question if you use math-type / LaTex formatting.