# If $p|s$ for some $s \in S$ then $p/1 \in (S^{-1}R)^*$, where $p$ prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, localization

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $S \subset R$ a multiplicative subset, such that $0 \notin S$. Let $p$ be a prime element of $R$. If $p|s$ for some $s \in S$ then $p/1 \in (S^{-1}R)^*$.

My attempt: If I am able to prove that $1/p \in S^{-1}R$, I am done. We know that $\exists r \in R: s=pr$. That means, $r/pr \in S^{-1}R$. I see that $r/pr$ and $1/p$ are equivalent, but can I even write $1/p$, since I don't know if $p \in S$? Also I don't know where I'm supposed to use that $p$ is prime (this is just the first part of the exercise, so it is possible that it doesn't come in play here).

Comment: "$p$ prime" is useless and what you said is sufficient: $1/p=r/s.$

Comment: Divisors of units are units [by a one-line proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3810819/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is essentially correct... except that you can't talk about $\frac{1}{p}$ unless $p$ lies in $S$, you are correct about that. That's why the problem is phrased the way it is: to show that $\frac{p}{1}$ is a unit. You can't "cancel" in the fraction, because only fractions with denominators in $S$ are allowed in $S^{-1}R$.  So what you need to do is show that they are inverses by multiplying them out and showing the result is equal, in $S^{-1}R$, to $1_{S^{-1}R}$.

Indeed, the fact that $p$ is prime is irrelevant.

**Proposition.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring, not necessarily a domain, let $S$ be a multiplicative subset (not necessarily containing $1$), and let $\varphi\colon R\to S^{-1}R$   be the canonical map (sending $r\in R$ to $\frac{rt}{t}$ for some $t\in S$; this is well-defined and independent of the choice of $t$). If $x\in R$ divides some element of $S$, then $\varphi(x)$ is a unit in $S^{-1}R$.

If $1\in S$, then you can take the map $\varphi$ to be $\varphi(r)=\frac{r}{1}$.

*Proof.* Let $s\in S$ and $y\in R$ be such that $s=xy$. We show that $\frac{y}{s}\in S^{-1}R$ is the inverse of $\varphi(x)$. Indeed, we have $\varphi(x)\frac{y}{s} = \frac{xs}{s}\frac{y}{s} = \frac{xsy}{ss}$. We prove that this is equal to $\frac{s}{s}\in S^{-1}R$, as $\frac{s}{s}= 1_{S^{-1}R}$.

To show that $\frac{xsy}{ss}=\frac{s}{s}$ we need to show that there exists $s'\in S$ such that $s'(xyss-sss)=0$. But since $xyss=(xy)ss=sss$, we have $xyss-sss=0$, so taking $s'\in S$ arbitrary we have equality. Thus, $\frac{xys}{ss}=\frac{s}{s}=1_{S^{-1}R}$. This proves that $\varphi(x)$ is a unit in $S^{-1}R$, as desired. $\Box$

Comment: Simpler: divisors of units are units [by a one-line proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3810819/242)