# Prove: For all a, b, and c integers with a ≠ 0, if a | b and b | c, then a² | bc.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How can I prove this theorem? I thought of using the definition of divisibility that if $a | b$ if and only if there is an integer $c$ such that $b = ac$, but I have no idea how to do this.

Prove: For all a, b, and c integers with $a ≠ 0,$ if $a | b$ and $b | c$, then $a^2 | bc.$

Comment: If a|b and b|c, then what can you say about a|c? Can you combine that with what you know to get the answer?

Comment: $b=ak_1$ and $c=bk_2$ implies $bc=\ldots$

Comment: Hints: 1) Divisibility is transitive. 2) If $w|x$ and $y|z$, then $wy|xz$.

Comment: $$a,b≠0$$

$$\begin{cases} \frac ba \in\mathbb Z \\ \frac cb \in\mathbb Z\end{cases} \implies \frac ba \times \frac cb=\frac ca \in\mathbb Z $$

$$\frac{bc}{a^2}=\frac ba× \frac ca \in\mathbb Z.$$

Comment: Just do it.  What does $a|b$ *mean*?  It means that there is an integer, $m$ so that $b=ma$.  And what does $b|c$ mean?  It means there is an integer $n$ so that $c = bn$.  So if $c = bn$ and $b=am$ then what does $bc$ equal?  Is there an integer $K$ so that $bc=a^2K$?

Comment: By transitivity of divisibility $\,\color{#c00}a\mid b\mid \color{#c00}c\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{a\mid c},\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}{a\mid b} \,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}a\cdot \color{#0a0}{a\mid b}\cdot \color{#c00}c\,$ by the linked [Divisibility Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/40127/242) $\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to Math StackExchange!

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a \neq 0$.

Suppose $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$. We need to show that $a^2 \mid b \cdot c$.

Since $a \mid b$, we have $ b = a \cdot k_1$ with $k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, by the definition of divisibility.

For $a \mid b$, we also have $ c = a \cdot k_2$ with $k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Multiplying $b$ by $c$:

$
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
b \cdot c & = (a \cdot k_1) \cdot (a \cdot k_2) \\
 & = a^2 \cdot k_1 \cdot k_2 \\
 & = a^2 \cdot k_3 \text{, with } k_3 = k_1 \cdot k_2 \in \mathbb{Z} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$

Therefore, we have $a^2 \mid b \cdot c$ by the definition of divisibility.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the help. Should I assume that (a | b) and (a | c) even though the question says it is (a | b) and (b | c)?

Comment: Yes, @dalerottt. The only thing that the question gives you is that "For all $a, b,$ and $c$ integers with $a \neq 0$". The other part is an implication (if-then statement), you need to prove it.
Please, consider accepting my answer if I helped you.

Comment: Yes, it helped, thank you very much. I understand better.

Comment: @dalerottt: You wouldn't be _assuming_ $a\mid c$. It follows from the given premises. $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$ together imply $a\mid c$.