# The square of an integer is congruent to 0 or 1 mod 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a question from the free Harvard online abstract algebra [lectures](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra).  I'm posting my solutions here to get some feedback on them.  For a fuller explanation, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98291/autv-is-isomorphic-to-s-3) post.

This problem is from assignment 6.  The notes from this lecture can be found [here](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/openlearning/math222/files/notes/L6-N.pdf).

> a) Prove that the square $a^2$ of an integer $a$ is congruent to 0 or 1 modulo 4.
>   b) What are the possible values of $a^2$ modulo 8?

a) Let $a$ be an integer. Then $a=4q+r, 0\leq r<4$ with $\bar{a}=\bar{r}$.  Then we have $a^2=a\cdot a=(4q+r)^2=16q^2+8qr+r^2=4(4q^2+2qr)+r^2, 0\leq r^2<4$ with $\bar{a^2}=\bar{r^2}$.  So then the possible values for $r$ with $r^2<4$ are 0,1.  Then $\bar{a^2}=\bar{0}$ or $\bar{1}$.

b) Let $a$ be an integer. Then $a=8q+r, 0\leq r<8$ with $\bar{a}=\bar{r}$.  Then we have $a^2=a\cdot a=(8q+r)^2=64q^2+16qr+r^2=8(8q^2+2qr)+r^2, 0\leq r^2<8$ with $\bar{a^2}=\bar{r^2}$.  So then the possible values for $r$ with $r^2<8$ are 0,1,and 2.  Then $\bar{a^2}=\bar{0}$, $\bar{1}$ or $\bar{4}$.

Again, I welcome any critique of my reasoning and/or my style as well as alternative solutions to the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: In (a), I don't think, unless you're changing your definition of $r$ in the middle, that $r^2<4$ is necessarily true.  Suppose $a=3$ so that $q=0$ and $r=3$—shouldn't $r^2=9$?

Comment: Your reasoning for a) is slightly flawed, as we need not have $r^2<4$. Consider for example $a=3$, then $r^2=9$. But we can observe that $\bar{r^2}=1$.

Comment: Seems I was not the only one to observe that though.

Comment: Perhaps a little too abstract for my taste. Maybe also not absolutely clear from solution that mod $8$, all of $0$, $1$, and $4$ are actually achievable.  Also, there are little mistakes, for example we definitely do not have $r^2<8$.

Comment: It would help if you could provide *precise* links to the notes and exercises you are using. I could not find such based on the link you gave.

Comment: I see now.  I was trying too hard to shoehorn the equation for $a^2$ back into the division algorithm.  This is why I was trying to force $r^2$ to be less than 4 (or 8) instead of 16 (or 64).  @Bill:  The exercises given on the website are just a list of problems from Artin's Algebra so I link to them.  In the future I will include a link to the pdf of the notes provided with each lecture.  Thanks everyone for your time...

Comment: @jobrien929 I would advise that you not use artin's algebra to study from. Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/96526/5783

Comment: For these problems, I would just list the cases and inspect. $\pmod 4, 0^2=0, 1^2=1, 2^2=0, 3^2=1$  What more needs to be said?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the first one the idea of what you have done is right (although did you mean to say that since $0 \leq r < 4$, $0 \leq r^2 < 16$?). An alternative viewpoint is to look at it like this. Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on the integers by $x\sim y$ iff $x - y $ is a multiple of $4$. Then you can check that this is an equivalence relation, so that you know every integer in the universe is of the form $4k$, $4k+1$, $4k+2$, or $4k+3$. This is basically the division algorithm.

If you square each one of these, the first one is $16k^2 \equiv 0 $ mod $4$, the second is congruent to 1 mod 4, the third is congruent to zero mod 4 because $2^2 = 4$ and the last is congruent to 1 mod 4 because $(4k+3)^2 = 4(\text{stuff}) + 1$.

The second problem is a casebash too (just this time you're working mod 8 as you have done).

Alternatively, there is another way to look at this in terms of group theory. I'm mentioning this because you are studying groups and one way or another you will come to this. Consider the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group. For question (a), let $\pi$ be the canonical projection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/(4)$, where $(4)$ is the cyclic normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of all the multiples of $4$. $\pi$ is a map that sends each integer to its equivalence class, where the equivalence relation here is

$$x \sim y \hspace{3mm} \text{iff} \hspace{3mm} x - y \in (4).$$

Let us write $[a]$ for the equivalence class of an integer in the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/(4)$. Now multiplication in the quotient is well-defined because $(4)$ is a normal subgroup, so that $[a \times a] = [a] \times [a]$. There is no ambiguity in using $\times$ for both as it is just ordinary multiplication of integers.

What this means is when looking at the possible remainders of the square of an integer mod 4, you can just *concentrate* on calculating

$$ \begin{eqnarray} 
0^2 &\equiv& 0 \hspace{2mm} \text{mod} \hspace{2mm} 4\\
1^2 &\equiv& 1 \hspace{2mm} \text{mod} \hspace{2mm} 4 \\
2^2 &\equiv& 0 \hspace{2mm} \text{mod} \hspace{2mm} 4\\
3^2 &\equiv& 1 \hspace{2mm} \text{mod} \hspace{2mm} 4.
\end{eqnarray}$$ 
This is because given any integer $[a]$, $[a] = [0],[1],[2]$ or $[3]$. Similarly for (b) your problem reduces to calculating the squares of $0,1,2 \ldots 7$ mod $8$.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 19):

Suppose the integer $z$ is even. Write it as $z = 2n$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $z^2 = 4n^2$; $z$ is divisible by 4.  Suppose the integer $z$ is odd. Write it as $z = 2n + 1$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$; then $z^2 = 4n^2 + 4n + 1 = 4n(n+1) + 1.$

We have just shown that for any integer $z$, the square of $z$, when divided by 4 gives remainder 1 or 0.

Comment: Indeed $\rm\ mod\ 4\!:\ even^2\equiv \{0,\:2\}^2\equiv 0,\ \: odd^2\equiv \{1,\:3\}^2\equiv \{\pm 1\}^2 \equiv 1\:.$ Similarly $\rm\:mod\ 8\:,\:$ see my answer. $\ $

Comment: More generally $\, n\equiv r\pmod{\!2m}\Rightarrow n^2\equiv r^2\pmod{\!4m},\,$ a special case of [LTE = Lifting The Exponent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3847038/242)

Answer (score 7):

$$\begin{align}
x^2 \mod 4 &\equiv (x \mod 4)(x \mod 4) \pmod 4 \\
&\equiv \begin{cases}0^2 \mod 4 \\
                 1^2 \mod 4 \\ 
                 2^2 \mod 4 \\
                 3^2 \mod 4 \end{cases} \\
&\equiv \begin{cases}0 \mod 4 \\
                 1 \mod 4 \\ 
                 4 \mod 4 \\
                 9 \mod 4 \end{cases} \\
&\equiv \begin{cases}0 \mod 4 \\
                 1 \mod 4 \\ 
                 0 \mod 4 \\
                 1 \mod 4 \end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $ $ Division $\rm\Rightarrow n = 4q\! +\! r,\ r\in \{0\ 1\ 2\ 3\}\Rightarrow n^2 = (4q\!+\!r)^2 =$ $\rm\: 4(\color{#0a0}{4q^2\!+\!2qr})\!+\!r^2 = $ $\rm\:4\color{#0a0}Q\! +\! \color{#c00}{r^2}.\,$ For the  remainder of $\rm\,\color{#c00}{r^2}\,$  note: $\,\rm r\in \{0\ 1\ 2\ 3\}$ $\rm\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{r^2 = \,4 \bar q + \bar r},\ \bar r\in \{0\ 1\},\,$  so $\rm \, n^2 = 4Q\!+\!\color{#c00}{4\bar q + \bar r}$

It's simpler in modular language $\rm\ mod\ 4\!:\ n\equiv r\ \Rightarrow\ n^2 \equiv r^2\equiv \{0\ 1\ 2\ 3\}^2\equiv \{0\ 1\ \color{#c00}4\ \color{#0a0}9\}\equiv  \{\color{#c00}0\ \color{#0a0}1\}\, $ by the [Congruence Product Rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39899/242) or working in the quotient / residue ring $\rm\ \mathbb Z/4\, =\, \mathbb Z\ mod\ 4.$

Optimization: work is *halved* by employing a *balanced* residue system, e.g. $\rm\: \pm \{0\ 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\}\ mod\ 8.\ $  Using that we quickly compute $\rm\ mod\ 8\!:\ odd^2\equiv \{ 1 \ 3\}^2 \equiv 1,\ \: even^2 \equiv \{0\ 2\ 4\}^2 \equiv \{0\  4\}.$

Or we can halve the cases using  $\ \rm n\equiv r\pmod{\!2m}\Rightarrow n^2\equiv r^2\pmod{\!4m}\,$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2020827/242).

[Generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/910/242) $\,n=24\,$ is largest integer satsifying $\,(a,n)=1\Rightarrow a^2\equiv 1\pmod{\! n}$.

Comment: it works one way only. because ${5 \equiv 1 (mod4) }$, but it is not a square in Z.

Comment: @SSA The question is not concerned with the truth of the converse.

Answer (score 2):

The glitch I am going to point out is not very serious, though keeping tracking of such things helps.

For instance, in (a), how is $0\leq r^2<4$. Consider a number of the form $4q+2$, you'll have an issue. But, however, what follows this error, $\bar a^2=\bar r^2$ is correct. But Why? Because, the the remainder when $ a^2$ is divided by $4$ is the same as that when $ r^2$ is divided by $4$ is what the equation reads and what you have proved.

So, to really complete the solution, you need to take a case-by-case approach. For various possible values of $r$, prove that $\bar r^2$ is as claimed.

**Remark:** It is an equivalence that $a=4q+r, 0\leq r<4 \iff \bar a=\bar r$. So, your statement that, "[...]Then $a=4q+r,0 \leq r<4~ \text {with}~ \bar a=\bar r$[...]" is a little clumsy.

The same remarks go for (b).

Hope this helps.