# Prove if $2\mid(x^2-1) $, then $4\mid(x^2-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have no idea where to start. Any hint(s) or suggestions?
Prove if $2\mid(x^2-1) $, then $4\mid(x^2-1)$

Comment: Hint: $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$.

Comment: One can actually show that $8|(x^2-1)$.

Comment: You can simply consider two cases. What happens if $x$ is even (i.e., $x=2n$ for some $n$)? What happens for $x=2n+1$ (=odd)? Something similar as in this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99716/the-square-of-an-integer-is-congruent-to-0-or-1-mod-4/99741#99741

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $2\mid (x^2-1)$. Then $2\mid (x-1)(x+1)$.

By [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma), either $2\mid (x+1)$ [or](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inclusive_or) $2\mid (x-1)$.

But $x+1$ is even [if and only if](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) $x-1$ is even. Thus, both must be even.

The product of two even numbers must be divisible by four, so $$4\mid (x^2-1)$$

Comment: wait. I'm confused here. for the euclid's lemma, is that supposed to be and?

Comment: Euclid's lemma only implies that *at least* one of the two is true, so I used the inclusive or.

Comment: It happens to be the case that both of the statements are true, in your problem. But Euclid's lemma doesn't imply that in general, because it's not true in general. For example, $6$ is even, but that doesn't mean *both* $2 \mid 2$ and $2 \mid 3$ (the latter is clearly false).

Answer (score 4):

One way is that the assumption implies that $x$ must be odd, so $x=2n+1$ and thus $$x^2=4n^2+4n+1$$

Answer (score 4):

$x-1$ and $x+1$ are separated by $2$ so they are either both odd or both even. The first case means that the product will not be divisible by two, so the second case must hold true.

Hence $2|(x-1)(x+1) \implies 2|(x+1)$ and $2|(x-1)$ so $4|(x-1)(x+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2\equiv1\pmod2\iff x\equiv1\pmod2,x=2a+1$ where $a$ is any integer

$$\implies x^2=(2a+1)^2=8\frac{a(a+1)}2+1\equiv1\pmod8$$