# Perfect square is $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$ .

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, square-numbers

Prove that for every integer $n$ either

- $n^2 \equiv 0\pmod{4}$ or
- $n^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$

Comment: Couldn't you just write out the 4 cases, of 0,1,2, and 3 mod 4 and get the desired answers?

Comment: Just calculate $1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 0^2$ and look for the remainder...

Comment: Or, you know, ... search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The square of an integer is congruent to 0 or 1 mod 4](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99716/the-square-of-an-integer-is-congruent-to-0-or-1-mod-4)

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*:

If $n = 2k$, $$n^2 = 4k^2$$
If $n = 2k+1$, $$n^2 = (2k+1)^2 = 4k^2+4k+1 = 4(k^2+k)+1$$

Answer (score 3):

$n$ can be even or odd.

When $n=2k$ we get

$(2k)^2=4k^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

When $n=2k+1$ we get

$n^2 = (2k+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.