# How to make a perfect square integer from two other integers?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

If I have a pair of integers, $X$ and $Y$, I would like to find an integer 
$\lambda$  such that 
            $$ X - \lambda Y  = t^2 $$
where $t$ is any other integer. All these integers can be either positive or negative.

Just wondering whether there is an simple formula or algorithm for finding either one or all the solutions.

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to when is $X$ a square modulo $Y$. This problem is completely solved. Search for the theory of congruence equations, in particular [quadratic congruence equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue).

Answer (score 3):

All perfect squares are [congruent to either $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99716/the-square-of-an-integer-is-congruent-to-0-or-1-mod-4).

So $3-4\lambda$ is not a perfect square for any integer $\lambda$.

Comment: How about the case where this condition is met.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. At most it only gives a criterion to know some of the cases, in which the algorithm (whose existence is being asked) should return no solutions.

Comment: fair enough, I read it initially as asking if such a $\lambda$ always exists.