# If $T$ is an odd number, how to show $-T^2=3(mod 4)$?

Tags: number-theory

I see it in a popular science book, but there is not any proof. And  I try some numbers, for example, $T=1,3$.  Since I really have not any knowledge of number theory. So, I asked here. Maybe, it is such  easy  that it is not suitable asked. If so, after I know it, I will delete it. Thanks.

Comment: Just expand $(2n+1)^2$ and watch almost everything disappear mod $4$.

Comment: If $T=2n+1$, what’s $-T^2-3$?

Comment: The proof ***is*** just to try for $T=1$ and $T=3$, since those are the only odd numbers (mod 4).

Comment: Thanks all, I really be not clever,,,

Comment: It's not about "being clever" (fixed mindset). You admittedly don't have knowledge of number theory, and I'm sure the commenters all do. If you study (growth midset) number theory, you'll know these things (and more).

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99716/the-square-of-an-integer-is-congruent-to-0-or-1-mod-4).

Answer (score 1):

If $T=2n+1$, then $T^2= 4n^2+4n+1$.  Working mod $4$, this is $1$, but $-1 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.