# Prove by induction for all integers

Tags: induction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111103/prove-by-induction)

I am stuck with my maths assignment. I need to prove for all integers $n\geq 1$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(3i-1)^2=\frac{1}{2}n(6n^2+3n-1)\;.$$