# Use induction to prove $\sum_{i=0}^n i^3 = (\sum_{i=0}^n i)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

> Use induction to prove $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n i^3 = \Bigl(\sum_{i=0}^n i\Bigr)^2$

How do I prove this using Induction?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996083/induction-proof-for-a-summation-sum-i-1n-i3-left-sum-i-1n-i-right , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111443/prove-13-23-cdots-n3-1-2-cdots-n2-using-inductio , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $1^3+ 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct)