# How to deduce that $1\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 2 + 3\cdot 1+3\cdot 2+3\cdot 3 +...+(n\cdot n) = n(n+1)(n+2)(3n+1)/24$

Tags: summation, induction

I know how to reason $$1\cdot2 + 2\cdot3 + 3\cdot4 + n(n-1) = \frac{1}{3}n(n-1)(n+1)$$

However, I'm stuck on proving $$1\cdot1 + (2\cdot1 + 2\cdot2) + (3\cdot1+3\cdot2+3\cdot3) + \cdots +(n\cdot 1+...+n\cdot n) = \frac{1}{24}n(n+1)(n+2)(3n+1).$$
Could somebody shed some light on me?

Comment: Try proof by induction ?

Comment: What's the difference between the first two lines?

Comment: First two lines are identical, and there also seem to be missing some points in $\;3\cdot 4+\ldots+n(n-1)\;$ ...

Comment: I just removed the identical two lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do as the following :$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(1+2+\cdots+k)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\\&=\frac 12\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3+\frac 12\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2\\&=\frac 12\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2+\frac 12\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.\end{align}$$

Comment: Requires knowledge of sum of $k$ - tell the story about a young [bugger - I don't know it myself] who was given the question by a teacher to add all the numbers from 1 to 100 and did the "arrange the pairs, 1 with 99, 2 with 98 .... " - Gauss maybe?

Comment: @AlecTeal: You are right. And I now found "induction" tag... Anyway, I leave my answer in hoping that my answer helps 'future readers'.

Comment: @mathlove oh the answer isn't useless! Just there's a nice story about the inuition

Comment: I'm adding these two links for my personal note (as my edit wasn't get approved): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16 for calculating sum of powers (2 and 3) of positive integers. Thanks everybody again!

Answer (score 3):

Base case:

Prove true for n=1

$ 1 * 1 = \frac{1(1 + 1)(1 + 2)(3(1) + 1)}{24} $

Inductive step:

Assume for n = k, prove for n = k+1. If we let the property be equal to P(n)

$ P(k+1) = P(k) + ((k+1) * 1 + ... +(k+1)*(k+1)) $

$ P(k+1) = \frac{k(k + 1)(k + 2)(3k + 1)}{24} + ((k+1) * 1 + ... +(k+1)*(k+1)) $

From here you should be able to do the rest, ask if you have any more issues

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

A similar but slightly different variation of Jack's proof above.

$$\begin{align}
&1\cdot (1)\\
+&2\cdot(1+2)\\
+&3\cdot(1+2+3)\\
+&4\cdot(1+2+3+4)\\
+&\vdots\qquad\vdots \; \quad\ddots\quad \ddots\\
+&n\cdot(1+2+3+\cdots+n)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ni\sum_{j=1}^i j=\sum_{i=1}^ni\sum_{j=1}^i {j\choose 1}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ni{i+1\choose 2}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left[(i+2){i+1\choose 2}-2{i+1\choose 2}\right]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left[3{i+2\choose 3}-2{i+1\choose 2}\right]\\
&=3{n+3\choose 4}-2{n+2\choose 3}\\
&={n+2\choose 3}\left[3\left(\frac{n+3}4\right)-2\right]
\qquad\qquad\text{using }{n+3\choose 4}=\frac{n+3}4{n+2\choose 3}\\
&=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}\cdot \left[ \frac{3n+1}4\right]\\
&=\frac1{24}n(n+1)(n+2)(3n+1)\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

---

NB - the above makes use of the identity
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{i+m\choose m+1}={n+1+m\choose m+2}$$

Comment: @PaulLo :You're welcome. $\binom nr$ refers to the binomial coefficient or combination function, and is sometimes written as $^nC_r$, and is defined as $$\binom nr=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-r+1)}{1\cdot 2\cdots r}$$. More info here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out to be standing for combination function which I have learned, now I can understand your answer thoroughly :p

Answer (score 1):

The combinatorial identity:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{K}\binom{n+k}{n}=\binom{n+K+1}{n+1}\tag{1}$$
can be easily proved by induction. It gives:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j(j+1) = 2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\binom{j+1}{2} = 2\binom{n+1}{3} = \frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{2}\tag{2}$$
as well as:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{k=1}^{n}k(1+2+\ldots+k) &=& 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\binom{k+1}{2}=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k+1}{2}+6\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k+1}{3}\\&=&2\binom{n+2}{3}+6\binom{n+2}{4}.\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you mean ${n+2\choose 3}$ rather than ${n+2\choose 2}$?

Comment: @hypergeometric: yes, sure, now fixed.