# Summing the terms of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have a really confusing question from an investigation. It states-

Find the value of:

$$\sqrt{1^3+2^3+3^3+\ldots+100^3}$$

How would I go about answering this??

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem. For example, have you tried to come up with a formula for adding the first $n$ cubic numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $1^3+ 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ using induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct)

Answer (score 7):

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3=\frac {n^2(n+1)^2}{2^2}=\left(\sum_{r=1}^nr\right)^2\\
\sqrt{\sum_{r=1}^{100}r^3}=\sum_{r=1}^{100}r=\binom{101}2=5050$$
i.e.
$$\sqrt{1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+100^3}=1+2+3+\cdots+100=5050$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: show by induction that $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}.$$

Note that the right-hand side is just $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

Prove by induction that $$1^3+2^3+3^3+\ldots + n^3 = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^2$$
and use that result in your question.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^{2}}{4}$$

Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

And if you don't know the formula
and don't need it exactly,

$\sum_{k=1}^{100} k^3
\approx \int_0^{100} x^3 dx
=\frac{100^4}{4}
$
so the result is
$\sqrt{\frac{100^4}{4}}
=\frac{100^2}{2}
=5000
$.

If you add in the
usual correction of
$\frac12 f(n)$,
the result is
$\sqrt{\frac{100^4}{4}+\frac12 100^3}
=\frac{100^2}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{100}}
\approx \frac{100^2}{2}(1+\frac{1}{100})
=5050
$.

Shazam!

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice visual proof (of concept) of the [Nicomachus's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NicomachussTheorem.html): the sum of first cubes is a squared triangular number:

[image: Wikipedia: Nichomacus theorem]

So the square root of the total volume of the cubes above is the side of the square below, hence the sum of the first integers.

In this  example, you have $225$ "unit cubes", whose root is $15$, i. e. the length of the side of the square below.

It takes some more time to draw $100$ increasing cubes, but the proof works along the same lines.