# Secondary school level mathematical induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

1. It is given that 
   $$1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+n^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$

Then, how to find the value of 
$2^3+4^3+\cdots+30^3$? 
Which direction should I aim at?

2. Prove by mathematical induction, that $5^n-4^n$ is divisible by 9 for all positive even numbers $n$.

$$5^n-4^n=9m,\text{where $m$ is an integer.}$$

What I am thinking in the $n+1$ step is,

\begin{align}
& 5^{n+2}-4^{n+2} \\
= {} & 5^2(5^n-4^n)+5^24^n-4^{n+2} \\
= {} & 5^2(5^n-4^n)+4^n(5^2-4^2) \\
= {} & 5^29m+4^n9 \\
= {} & 9(5^2m+4^n)
\end{align}

Does this approach make sense?

3. Show that $a+b$ is a factor of $a^n+b^n$ where $n$ is a positive odd number.

I am thinking this in the $n+1$ step.
$$a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}$$
But then I cannot get it further.

Comment: You have three questions here. Please restrict yourself to one question per post--you can ask the other two questions in separate posts.

Comment: I will separate them cuz i was afraid I asking similar questions in related posts.

Comment: 1) Honestly, I'd come up with a new equation altogether.  There are principals to modify it to all even numbers but the are not direct.  2) Why are you trying to figure for n +2?  Induction wants n+1.  Otherwise it is good.  3) Well... For odd numbers you don't want an n+1 step but an n+2 step.  If n is odd, the *next* odd number is n+2.  Or if you want you can convert n to 2k + 1 (not n; need a new variable) and then the induction step is on k+1 to 2(k+1) + 1 = 2k + 3.

Comment: D'oh.  1) Factor out $2^3 = 8$ from all the terms.... (what the heck is *wrong* with me this morning????)

Comment: You should drink a coffee first ;)

Comment: For your first question, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct).

Comment: @Martin Sleziak I am not asking how to prove it but how to find $2^3+4^3+\cdots+30^3$

Comment: Well, if you know that formula, all you have to do is plug $n=30$ into the formula and subtract $1=1^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a hint for the first one. Since you have asked three different questions, I wait to see if they tell you to split your question in there questions...

**1**

You already have a formula:

$$1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \ldots  + n^3 = \frac{n^2((n+1)^2)}{4}$$

Hence in your case $n = 30$ **but** your sum starts from $2^3$ and not from $1^3$, hence you have to subtract $1^3$ (namely one):

$$2^3 + 3^3 + \ldots + 30^3 = \frac{30^2(30+1)^2}{4} - 1 = \frac{30^2\cdot 31^2}{4} - 1 = 216224$$

**Edit because I understood nothing**

Since you want only the sum of even numbers, then you have:
$$2^3 + 4^3 + 8^3 + \ldots + 30^3 = 2^3(1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \ldots + 15^3) = 115200$$

Thanks to **Crostule** for notifying me.

Comment: Slightly more than a hint I'd say!

Comment: @Ed_4434 lol you're right. But at least he will understand how to proceed without mistakes!

Comment: Actually the correct sum is the one with even terms. So, it's $2^3(1^3+ \dots + 15^3)$

Comment: @Crostul Ah! Ops I missed the fact he wanted just the even ones -.-

Comment: @FourierTransform As did I hahaha

Comment: @Crostul Thanks! I think this makes sense!

Comment: @Fourier Transform Thanks for your reply anyway ;)

Comment: The OP question was $2^3 + 4^3 + 6^3....$ **not** $2^3 + 3^3 +4^3 + 5^3....$..  Crosul's sum is correct and .... D'oh!!! it must be early.  I thought of common factors and .... concluded it would be too hard.... d'oh!

Comment: EDITED. Sorry again for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Meh, happens to everyone.  Just take a gander at my idiotic comment on the main post!

Answer (score 1):

Hints

1) $2^3+4^3+...+30^3=2^3(1^3+2^3+...+15^3)$ now apply the formula you got.

2) Assume that $9k=5^n-4^n$ then $5^{n+2}-4^{n+2}=25.5^n-16.4^n=25(9k+4^n)-16.4^n=9k'+9.4^n$

3) Change the questions to show that $(a+b)|(a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1})$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.Let $(a+b)x=a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}$ now $a^{2k+3}+b^{2k+3}=a^2.a^{2k+1}+b^2.b^{2k+1}$ again do substitution and it will work out.

Answer (score 1):

1) $2^3 + 4^3 + 6^3 + .... +30^3 = 2^3*1^3 + 2^3*2^3 + 2^3*3^3 + ... + 2^3*15^3 = 2^3(1^3 + 2^3 + .... + 25^3)$

2) Perfect.  You did great.  (Better than I did when I didn't realize it was only true for even numbers.)

3) If $n$ is odd then you don't want $a^{2n+1} + b^{2n+1}$ for the inductive step but either: $a^{n+2} + b^{n+2}$ (much like you did in 2) or $n = 2k+1;$ inductive step on $a^{2(k+1) + 1} + b^{2(k+1)+1}$. 2 1/2) or $n = 2k-1$ and $b^{2k+1} + b^{2k +1}$.  Either way will work.

Answer (score 1):

For #3 use the technique of #2: For $n\in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ we have $$a^{2n+3}+b^{2n+3}=a^2(a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1})+(-a^2+b^2)b^{2n+1}=$$ $$=a^2(a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1})+(a+b)(b-a)b^{2n+1}.$$

Comment: $$a^n+b^n=(a+b)Q,\text{where $Q$ is a polynomial.}$$
\begin{align}
& a^{n+2}+b^{n+2} \\
= {} & a^2(a^n+b^n)-b^na^2+b^{n+2} \\
= {} & a^2(a+b)Q-b^n(a^2-b^2) \\
= {} & (a+b)(a^2Q-b^n(a-b))
\end{align}