# sum of perfect cubes formula proof without induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

is there any proof for the sum of cubes except induction supposition?
there are some proofs using induction in below page 
[Proving $1^3+ 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write

$$(k+1)^4 = k^4+4k^3+6k^2+4k+1$$

or

$$(k+1)^4 -k^4 = 4k^3+6k^2+4k+1.$$

If you sum both sides from $k=1$ to $n$, the left side telescopes
and you have

$$(n+1)^4 -1 = 4 \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3 + 6\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 + 4\sum_{k=1}^{n} k + \sum_{k=1}^{n} 1.$$  Using known formulae for the last 3 sums gives

$$(n+1)^4 -1 = 4 \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3 + 6 \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+4\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n$$

and you can solve this equation for the remaining sum.

Comment: how can we sum from (1+1)^4 to (n+1)^4 and it becomes (n+1)^4 again?

Comment: The left sum is $(2^4 - 1^4) + (3^4 - 2^4) + (4^4 - 3^4) + \cdots$, so every term cancels but the first and last.

Comment: thanks a lot. I understood

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

begin by
$$(n+1)^4=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1$$

...
$$(3+1)^4=3^4+4.3^3+6.3^2+4.3+1$$
$$(2+1)^4=2^4+4.2^3+6.2^2+4.2+1$$
$$(1+1)^4=1^4+4.1^3+6.1^2+4.1+1$$

and sum to get

$$(n+1)^4=1+4S_3+6S_2+4S_1+n $$
with
$$S_1=1+2+...+n=\frac {n (n+1)}{2}$$
$$S_2=1^2+2^2+...+n^2=\frac {n (n+1)(2n+1)}{6} $$

Now you can find your sum $S_3$.

Comment: can you explain a little more clearly  in the part you get to the sum

Comment: @f.jalili Look now if it is clearer.

Comment: @f.jalili There is telescopage.2^4,3^4,5^4...n^4 disapear.