# Review: Prove by induction Nicomachus's theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Please help me out reviewing the way I wrote this proof:

Prove by induction: $1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ with $n\geqslant1$

Proof:

Lets define the set, $S=\left \{n\in N:n\geqslant1, 1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2  \right \}$

If $n=1$ then, $1\in S$

Lets asume that $k\in S$ with $k\geqslant1$, then

$\begin{gather*} 1^3+2^3+3^3+...+k^3=\left(\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right)^2\\ 
\end{gather*}$

Now lets proof that $k+1\in S$,

$\begin{align*}1^3+2^3+3^3+...+k^3+(k+1)^3=&\left(\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right)^2+(k+1)^3\\ =&(k+1)^2\left (\frac{k^2}{4}+(k+1)\right)\\=&(k+1)^2 \left(\frac{(k^2+4k+4)}{4} \right)\\ =&(k+1)^2 \left(\frac{(k+2)^2}{4}\right)\\ =&\left(\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}\right)^2 \end{align*}$

Which is true.

Comment: A totally valid induction proof

Comment: nitpick missing a parenthesis in the last line.

Comment: A similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct

Comment: Actually is not similar, I'm trying to improve my proof writing and I've been posting this kind of proofs so other people help me reviewing them. In that post he is looking for the proof.

Comment: Ty @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: @Mr.LU I am aware of that, that's why I said *'similar'* and not *'duplicate'*. However, note that some other users may disagree, and mark it as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: Your proof is written in a very similar way as [@alok's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct/62198#62198).

Comment: You may want to write out the base case ... otherwise good job!

Comment: That's true @projectilemotion. Should I avoid posting my proofs as new posts? I´m rather new and don't want to break any rules, I found this site crazy useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the proof seems okay to me.