# How to find arithmetic mean of number

Tags: sequences-and-series, means, arithmetic-progressions, mathematica, geometric-progressions

The arithmetic mean of 1,8,27,64... upto n terms is given by ....
I know the formula for arithmetic mean
But i don't know how to apply it
I applied a+b/2
But it's  not logical here so 
Plzz tell me the exact solution of
This question

Ans is n (n+1)^2/4

Plzz explain me in a detail

Comment: Use please LaTeX.

Comment: Plzz specify in more detail

Comment: Plzz avd txtspk.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2598637/sum-of-the-cubes-of-the-first-n-natural-numbers?rq=1

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm new on this app nd i don't understand what r u saying

Comment: This isn't an "app".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers are perfect cubes.

So, you want
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^3}n$$ Use [Faulhaber's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Answer (score 0):

$$(n+1)^4-1=\sum_{k=1}^n((k+1)^4-k^4)=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n(4k^3+6k^2+4k+1)=4\sum_{k=1}^nk^3+n(n+1)(2n+1)+2n(n+1)+n.$$
Can you end it now?