# Induction to prove that...

Tags: logic, induction

How can I use induction to prove that

$1^2+3^2+...+(2n+1)^2=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}{3}$ for non-negative integers $n$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I would start with $n=1$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Nothing because I don't know where to start.

Comment: If you don't know that you should start by checking whether it holds or not when $n=1$, then perhaps that you should learn about induction from the start.

Comment: Every statement of the form $f(0)+f(1)+\cdots+f(n)=g(n)$ can be proved by verifying two things: (i) $g(0)=f(0)$ and (ii) $g(n+1)-g(n)=f(n+1)$.

Comment: Try to follow the given hints and show your work here, we'll take a look to it! You can also check on MSE network for similar questions to have a guide. Good work!

Comment: Take a look here for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct

Comment: @user557276 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that proof by induction require two steps

**1. Base case**

- we need to check that the statement is true for $n=1$

**2. Induction step**

- assume $1^2+3^2+...+(2n+1)^2=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}{3}$ as hypotesis and by that try to prove that the following holds

$$1^2+3^2+...+(2n+1)^2+2[(n+1)+1]^2=\frac{[(n+1)+1][2(n+1)+1][2(n+1)+3]}{3}$$