# Sum of quadratic series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, induction

I just found out that
$$\sum _{i=0}^n\:i^2= \frac{n\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}{6}$$
and 
$$\sum _{i=0}^n\:i^3 = \frac{n^2\left(n+1\right)^2}{4}$$
but I don't understand how did we get the expression $\frac{n\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}{6}$ from this $\sum _{i=0}^n\:i^2$.

Can you help me with this. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: definitely a duplicate

Comment: It can be proved with induction.

Comment: See also [How to prove the sum of cubes formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62171)